# How do you prove Gautschi's inequality for the gamma function?

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

[A](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47261) [few](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15210) [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69164) here on math.SE have used as an intermediate step the following inequality that is due to Walter Gautschi:

$$x^{1-s} < \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)} < (x+1)^{1-s},\qquad x > 0,\; 0 < s < 1$$

Unfortunately, [the paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/sapm195938177) that the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.i) is pointing to is not easily accessible. How might this inequality be proven?

Comment: Note: I'm actually planning to answer this question a bit later; I have managed to acquire a copy of Gautschi's paper, and I will type up a summary as an answer. But I want to see how others might go about proving it without seeing Gautschi's route. I'll probably leave this standing for two days before posting a summary of Gautschi's paper.

Comment: I assume that you've seen [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2007604) by Laforgia (also referred to in DLMF). Is there a reason you don't mention it?

Comment: Laforgia can be downloaded from: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1984-42-166/S0025-5718-1984-0736455-1/home.html

Comment: @J.M. The Laforgia article seems to say that Gautschi requires your $x$ to be a positive integer. I do not like the notation, Laforgia uses the same letter $k$ to be integral sometimes and sometimes real...

Comment: @t.b. I have a copy, but it deals with a slightly different inequality from Gautschi's, and I was really looking for an excuse to post Gautschi's proof since the *J. Math. Phys.* archives have yet to be digitized... (aside: that journal's a real goldmine... MIT really should look into digitizing it.)

Comment: @Will: Don't worry; as I said, I have Gautschi's paper, and he in fact proves a slightly more general inequality (involving the incomplete gamma function) that applies for positive real $x$, and the inequality in the OP drops out as a special case.

Comment: @J.M.  Fair enough

Comment: @J.M.: since the inequality is two-sided, one could call this, with a bit of mispronunciation, the Goat-Cheese Sandwich Theorem.

Comment: @rob mmm, sandwich... :D indeed, it's a very nice bracketing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'll probably leave this standing for two days before posting a summary of Gautschi's paper.

Here is the *long-overdue* follow-through. I have slightly changed a few notations, but this is otherwise Gautschi's original argument.

---

What Gautschi actually proves in his paper is the more general inequality

$$\exp((s-1)\psi(n+1))\le\frac{\Gamma(n+s)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\le n^{s-1},\; 0\le s\le1,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}\tag{1}\label{1}$$

where $\psi(n)$ is the digamma function.

Gautschi considers the function

$$f(s)=\frac1{1-s}\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+s)}{\Gamma(n+1)}\right)$$

over $0\le s <1$, from which we have $f(0)=\log(1/n)$ and

$$\lim_{s\to 1}f(s)=-\psi(n+1)$$

via l'Hôpital. Then we have

$$(1-s)f'(s)=f(s)+\psi(n+s)$$

and then by letting

$$\varphi(s)=(1-s)(f(s)+\psi(n+s))$$

we have $\varphi(0)=\psi(n)-\log n<0$, $\varphi(1)=0$, and $\varphi'(s)=(1-s)\,\psi ^{(1)}(n+s)$ (where $\psi ^{(1)}(n)$ is the trigamma function).

Now, since $\psi ^{(1)}(n+s)=\psi ^{(1)}(s)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(s+k)^2}$ is always positive, we have that $\varphi(s)<0$, from which we deduce that $f(s)$ is monotonically decreasing over $0<s<1$ (i.e., $f'(s)<0$). Therefore

$$-\psi(n+1)\le f(s)\le\log\frac1{n}$$

which is equivalent to $\eqref{1}$. The inequality in the OP can then be deduced from the inequality $\psi(n)<\log n$.

Answer (score 50):

The strict log-convexity of $\Gamma$ (see the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101007/)) implies that for $0< s <1$,
$$
\Gamma(x+s)<\Gamma(x)^{1-s}\Gamma(x+1)^s=x^{s-1}\Gamma(x+1)\tag{1}
$$
which yields
$$
x^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}\tag{2}
$$
Again by the strict log-convexity of $\Gamma$,
$$
\Gamma(x+1)<\Gamma(x+s)^s\Gamma(x+s+1)^{1-s}=(x+s)^{1-s}\Gamma(x+s)\tag{3}
$$
which yields
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}<(x+s)^{1-s}<(x+1)^{1-s}\tag{4}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(4)$ yields
$$
x^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}<(x+1)^{1-s}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Note that $(5)$ gives $\Gamma(x+s)=\Gamma(x)x^se^{O(1/x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $a,b\geq 0$, let us consider the function $f(x)=x^{a}(1-x)^{b}$ on the interval $[0,1]$.
Its maximum value is given by $\frac{a^a b^b}{(a+b)^{a+b}}$, since $f'$ only vanishes at $x=\frac{a}{a+b}$.
For any $p>0$ we have
$$ \| f\|_p^p = \int_{0}^{1}x^{pa}(1-x)^{pb}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(ap+1)\,\Gamma(bp+1)}{\Gamma((a+b)p+2)} $$
and [the LHS is log-convex with respect to $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880656/log-convexity-of-the-p-norms-of-a-fixed-function). By considering that
$$ \lim_{p\to +\infty}\|f \|_p = \frac{a^a b^b}{(a+b)^{a+b}} $$
Gautschi's inequality turns out to be a simple consequence of [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Thorin_theorem) and a suitable choice of the parameters $a,b,p$.