# Upper bound for the quotient of gamma functions?

Tags: inequality, special-functions, gamma-function

I am looking for an upper bound for

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x+\beta)}{\Gamma(x)},\,\,\,\beta>0.$$

[In this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/117977) it was shown that

$$ \frac{\Gamma(x+\beta)}{\Gamma(x)} \approx x^\beta. $$

Then, I believe that there must be some sort of polynomial upper bound but I have failed to come up with one. This is true for the case when $\beta$ [is an integer](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/introductions/Gamma/05/). Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\beta$ is an integer then from $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$ we have

$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+\beta)}{\Gamma(x)} = \prod_{k=0}^{\beta-1} (x+k).
$$

Otherwise we can use the monotonicity of $\Gamma$ can obtain the crude bound

$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+\beta)}{\Gamma(x)} = \frac{\Gamma(x + \beta - \lceil\beta\rceil)}{\Gamma(x)} \prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\beta\rceil} (x+\beta-k) \leq \prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\beta\rceil} (x+\beta-k)
$$

which holds for $x + \beta - \lceil\beta\rceil \geq x_0$, where $x_0 \approx 1.46163$ is the location of the minimum of the gamma function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: For my specific purpose this answer is enough, then I am going to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Gabo You might want to wait a day or so before accepting an answer.  It's possible that someone who can give a better estimate than mine just hasn't seen the question yet! :)

Comment: In particular it looks like $\Gamma(x+\beta) \leq x^\beta$ for all $x \geq 0$ if $0 < \beta < 1$, which could be used to improve my bound quite a bit.  I don't see how to prove it though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\Gamma(x + 1) \sim {x^x e^{-x}\over \sqrt{2\pi x}}$$
by the Stirling formula.  So
$${\Gamma(x + 1 + \beta )\over \Gamma(x + 1)}\sim {(x + \beta)^{x + \beta}\over
x^x}\cdot{\sqrt{2\pi x}\over\sqrt{2\pi (x + \beta)}}\cdot e^{-\beta}
\sim (1 + \beta/x)^x e^{-\beta} \cdot (x + \beta)^\beta
\sim(x + \beta)^\beta \sim x^\beta.$$

Comment: Gabo already gave a link in their question to an answer which shows this.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,
$$
\Gamma(x+\beta)\le x^\beta \Gamma(x).
$$
See a proof in a short note published by James G. Wendel in 1948.

J. G. Wendel (1948): Note on the Gamma function, Amer. Math. Monthly. Vol. 55, No. 9, pp. 563--564.

DOI: 10.2307/2304460.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2304460