# approximation for $\Gamma (\alpha) / \Gamma (\beta) $ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary numbers in $R^{+}$

Tags: approximation, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I am working on implementation of a machine learning method that in part of the algorithm I need to calculate the value of $\Gamma (\alpha) / \Gamma (\beta) $. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are quite large numbers (i.e. bigger than 200) and it causes the python $gamma$ function to overflow. However, as the difference of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is relatively small (e.g. $|\alpha-\beta|<5$), the final result is not such a big number and can be used for later purposes. So, I am trying to calculate (or approximate) the value of $\Gamma (\alpha) / \Gamma (\beta) $ without going through the calculation of $\Gamma (\alpha)$ and $\Gamma (\beta)$ directly. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were integers, the result would be simple equal to $\alpha . \alpha+2. \alpha+3... \beta-1$, But I can not imagine how this formula will be changed if we let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be real numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure how precise your values need to be, but have you tried expanding using Stirling's Approximation?

Comment: No, actually I didn't hear about this approximation. thank you

Comment: A prior question that might be useful:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117977/quotient-of-gamma-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a good solution would be Stirling approximation that is to say $$\log(\Gamma(x))=x (\log (x)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(-\log \left({x}\right)+\log (2 \pi
   )\right)+\frac{1}{12 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ Now, consider $$y=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)}\implies \log(y)=\log(\Gamma(\alpha))-\log(\Gamma(\beta))$$ Apply the formula (even with more terms) and use later $y=e^{\log(y)}$.

You are then able to control overflows and underflows if required.

By the way, why not to use in Python function **lgamma(x)** ?

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of lgamma function. It seems that it solves the problem in addition to using the Stirling approximation directly.

Comment: @CoderInNetwork. Since I do not use Python, I did not know either. I just googled for *mathematical functions Python*. Using *lgamma(x)* will be much better than Stirling (I am sure). Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) we have Gautschi's inequality:

$$x^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}<(x+1)^{1-s},\quad x>0,0<s<1$$

We can combine this with the functional equation for the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$$
which holds for all $z$ where $\Gamma$ is defined.

Now, assume that $\alpha\leq\beta$, and that $|\beta-\alpha|\leq 5$.  Now, let $k$ be the greatest integer such that $\alpha+k\leq\beta$ (so clearly, $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.  It follows that $\alpha+k+s = \beta$ where $0\leq s<1$.

Now, we have that $\Gamma(\beta) = \Gamma(\alpha+k+s)$, and we can apply the functional equation $k+1$ times to get that $\Gamma(\beta) =\prod_{i = 0}^{k+1} (\alpha+k+s)\Gamma(\alpha-1+s)$.  It follows that:
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha+k+s)} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\prod_{i = 0}^k (\alpha+k+s)\Gamma(\alpha-1+s)}$$
Now, if we substitue in $\alpha-1 = x$, we see that:
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i = 0}^{k+1}((\alpha+k+s)}\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}$$
This part in the front is just some constant $c$, so we can rewrite this as:
$$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)} = c\frac{\Gamma((\alpha-1)+1)}{\Gamma((\alpha-1)+s)}$$
From Gautschi's inequality, we have that:
$$(\alpha-1)^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1+1)}{\Gamma(\alpha-1+s)}<\alpha^{1-s}$$
Now, as you said that $\alpha\gg 5$, we have that $c\geq 0$, so we can multiply through by $c$ to get that:
$$c(\alpha-1)^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)}<c\alpha^{1-s}$$
The above calculation implicitly assume that $s\neq 0,1$, but if this is true then we can get the result just from the functional equation for the gamma.  Moreover, $0<1-s<1$, so while $\alpha$ may be large, $\alpha^{1-s}$ is hopefully manageable.

This is all to try to give you another option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. up-voted.

Comment: You've written “$\Gamma(\beta) =\prod_{i = 0}^{k+1} (\alpha+k+s)\Gamma(\alpha-1+s)$”, where $\beta = \alpha + k + s$. But, why does $i$ not show up in the product? My analysis suggests that $\Gamma(\beta) = \Gamma(\alpha - 1 + s) \prod_{i=0}^k(\alpha - 1 + s + i)$ and I don't think that quite agrees?