# Is there a approximation for $\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu)\phi)}$?

Tags: statistics, optimization, self-learning, numerical-optimization

Is there a way to approximate the function below
$$\frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu)\phi)}$$
where $\phi$ and $\mu$ are real values?

I'm trying to fit some regression model in a package called R and I'm with some problems because in this model $\phi>600$ in some cases and `gamma()` function doesn't support such big values.

Comment: This is precisely a (inverted) Beta function, for which there exists good estimates.

Comment: R has the `lbeta()` and `lgamma()` functions giving logarithms of the Beta and Gamma functions, which should help with large parameters

Comment: A similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071332/approximation-for-gamma-alpha-gamma-beta-where-alpha-and-beta/2071341#2071341 for Python.

Answer (score 1):

This looks equal to $\frac{1}{{\rm {B}}(\mu\phi,\phi-\mu\phi)}$. There is a sharp inequality proved by Alzer, which reads:
\begin{align}
0 \le \frac{1}{xy}-{\rm {B}}(x,y) \le  0.08731, \qquad \forall x,y\ge1
\end{align}
The constants $``0"$ and $``0.08731"$ are best possible.

For $0\le x,y <1$, there  exists no upper bound. There are a lot of upper bounds But Alzer is the famous and explicit one. Hope this help.