# On a reference for $ \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {\Gamma (n+\alpha )}{\Gamma (n)n^{\alpha }}}=1,\qquad \alpha \in \mathbb {C} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, reference-request

I am looking for a proof of the following fact for reference

$$  \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {\Gamma (n+\alpha )}{\Gamma (n)n^{\alpha }}}=1,\qquad \alpha \in \mathbb {C}  $$

Where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. I would like to follow the entire proof so I am hoping it is not a multipager.

Comment: Sorry i didn't check conditions on $\alpha$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/117977

Comment: What's your definition of the Gamma function? For some, the given limit *is the basis for the definition*. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler.27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take logarithms
$$\log\left({\frac {\Gamma (n+\alpha )}{\Gamma (n)n^{\alpha }}}\right)=\log (\Gamma (n+\alpha ))-\log (\Gamma (n))-\alpha  \log (n)$$ and use Stirling approximation for large $p$
$$\log(\Gamma(p))=p (\log (p)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)+\log (2 \pi )\right)+\frac{1}{12 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ You should end with 
$$\log\left({\frac {\Gamma (n+\alpha )}{\Gamma (n)n^{\alpha }}}\right)=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac 1 {n^2}\right)$$