# What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)}{n^{\alpha+1} }$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, gamma-function

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$  then, I would like to compute
>    $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)}{n^{\alpha+1}
> }$$
>   where $\Gamma$ is the standard gamma function.

Comment: have you tried the stirling approximation?

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak, How would you apply Stirling on the negative real axis?

Comment: In order to avoid evaluating the $\Gamma$ function at a pole, you have to assume $\alpha\not\in\mathbb{N}$, too.

Comment: @AntonioVargas agreed, doesn't really help...

Comment: Using Euler reflection formula and Stirling approximation, you can check that $$ \frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)}{n^{\alpha+1}} = (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi \alpha} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}). $$ So the limit does not exist for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee the answer below says the does exist for none integer and the limit is  0 check the result and tell me

Comment: @GuyFsone, At the beginning of your answer, the formula should be corrected as $$ \Gamma(\varepsilon-n) = (-1)^n\frac{ \Gamma(1-\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon)}{ \Gamma(n+1-\varepsilon)}. $$ Notice the denominator for the difference. This matches with the Euler reflection formula as well as numerical computations. Although I haven't checked the rest, I guess that this fix will lead to the same answer.

Comment: Yes thank your right for the formula. But the result remain the same. nothing change.

Comment: @GuyFsone, Starting from the formula above, we get $$ \frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)}{n^{\alpha+1}} = (-1)^n \Gamma(\alpha+1)\Gamma(-\alpha) \underbrace{ \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)n^{1+\alpha}} }_{=:b_n}. $$ Then you can show that $b_n \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. (The link in your answer does prove this.) So something does really change.

Comment: Thank very much I have updated my answer.  That sign was extremely relevant. And rather your answer is correct as well

Answer (score 4):

[By Gamma extension formula we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

$$ \Gamma(\varepsilon-n) =(-1)^n\frac{ \Gamma(1-\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon)}{ \Gamma(n+1-\varepsilon)}~~~~0<\varepsilon<1~~n\in \Bbb N$$
**Also if $\alpha$ is an integer then the limit won't makes any sense, since the Gamma function does exists for negative integers. Therefore looking at the floor of $\alpha $, we have,**
$$\alpha  =m +\varepsilon~~~0<\varepsilon<1, ~~m\in \Bbb Z.$$

Now for $n>m,$ write

$$\color{red}{ \Gamma(\alpha-n+1) = \Gamma(\varepsilon-(n-m-1)) = (-1)^{n-m}\frac{ \Gamma(1-\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon)}{ \Gamma(n-m-\varepsilon)}}$$

That is, 
$$\color{red}{ \Gamma(\alpha-n+1) = (-1)^{n-m}\frac{ \Gamma(1-\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon)}{ \Gamma(n-\alpha)}}$$

Hence for $n>m,$

$$\color{blue}{ \Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)n^{-\alpha-1}  = (-1)^{n-m}\Gamma(1-\varepsilon)\Gamma(\varepsilon)\frac{\Gamma(n)n^{-\alpha}}{ \Gamma(n-\alpha)}.}$$

Nevertheless, from this [On a reference for $ \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {\Gamma (n+\alpha )}{\Gamma (n)n^{\alpha }}}=1,\qquad \alpha \in \mathbb {C} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431638/on-a-reference-for-lim-n-to-infty-frac-gamma-n-alpha-gamma-nn)
We have that,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)n^{-\alpha}}{ \Gamma(n-\alpha)} = 1.$$

> Conclusion, 
>   $$\color{blue}{ \lim_{n\to \infty}\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(\alpha-n+1)n^{-\alpha-1}  ~~~~~\text{Does not exist for any $\alpha\in \Bbb R$}}$$

Comment: I think you need more of a hint than that, since the argument of the second $\Gamma$ is going to $-\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar 
 
I have done Now the answer is: it does not exists