# Does this series converge: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots \cdot (2n-1)(-1)^n }{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdots (2n)}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following series converges? $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n-1)(-1)^n  }{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n)} $   Already concerned with the criteria of reason and Kummer

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? Save everyone a lot of work by warning of blind alleys.

Comment: Can you see that your $n$th term is $(-1)^n\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: Are you sure this starts at n = 0 or should that be n = 1?

Comment: @Amzoti For $n=0$, the interpretation is that both numerator and denominator are empty products, and equal to $1$.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the clarification - for some reason that threw me off.

Comment: You have an alternating series with terms that are decreasing in absolute value. Can you show that the terms converge to $0$? If you apply Stirling's formula, you can see that your terms have absolute value akin to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)}
&=\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots\cdot(2n)}{(2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n))^2}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdots\cdot n)^2}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\\
\end{align}$$

By [Stirling's Approximation for factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$\begin{align}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
&\leq\frac{e(2n)^{2n+1/2}e^{-2n}}{2^{2n}(\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n})^2}\\
&=\frac{e(2n)^{2n+1/2}e^{-2n}}{2^{2n}(2\pi)n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}\\
&=\frac{e(2n)^{1/2}}{(2\pi)n}\\
&=\frac{e(2n)^{1/2}}{(2\pi)n}\\
&=\frac{e}{\pi\sqrt{2n}}\longrightarrow0
\end{align}$$

So you have an alternating series whose terms converge to $0$. Also, $$\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots\cdot(2n-1)(2n+1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)(2n+2)}<\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot(2n)}$$
So your terms are decreasing in absolute value. The alternating series test guarantees convergence.

And you can even establish what the series converges to. 
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1/2}{n}x^n\\
\end{align}$$
where $x=1$. The change to $\binom{-1/2}{n}$ is easy enough to check, and is nice to know every now and then. This last expression is the powers series for $1/\sqrt{1+x}$. With $x=1$, we are right on the boundary of convergence. But we have already established that the series converges with $x=1$. By a theorem of Abel cited at the very beginning of [this paper](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/abelthm.pdf), we may conclude that the series sums to $1/\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer:**

Let

$$a_n= \frac{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n-1) }{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n)} \,.$$

Then

$$a_{n}=\frac{2n-1}{2n}a_{n-1} \,,$$ 
thus $a_n$ is decreasing.

Because of this, there are only two possible outcomes:

**Case 1:** $\lim_n a_n=0$, in which case you can use the Alternating Series Test.

**Case 2:** $\lim_n a_n \neq 0$, in which case the series is divergent.

So, basically your question reduces to: Is

$$\lim_n a_n =0 \, ? \,.$$

Comment: In your expressions for the limits, why do you just put $n$ instead of $n\to\infty$? What I mean is 

$\lim_n a_n$ vs. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Comment: @Joe, the $_{\to\infty}$ is taken as understood from the context.

Comment: @Gerry That's what I presumed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2 k - 1}{2 k}.$$  Then $$\arcsin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2n+1}x^{2 n + 1}$$ and in particular the series $\frac{a_n}{2n + 1}$ is summable with sum $\frac{\pi}{2}$. (For an elementary proof see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164889/why-do-the-endpoints-of-the-maclaurin-series-for-arcsin-converge/165064#165064) answer.) Since the series $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ is itself not summable and $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence this implies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ and therefore your alternating series is summable.