# How to prove that Taylor series for $\sin^{-1}(x)$ converges at $x=\pm1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Domain of convergence for $\sin^{-1}(x)$ was asked. I proved that its radius of convergence is $1$. I need to check its convergence at end points. Please tell me some convergence test or some way of proving its convergence at end points.

Comment: Have you encountered Stirling's approximation for factorials?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164889/why-do-the-endpoints-of-the-maclaurin-series-for-arcsin-converge/165064#165064).

Answer (score 1):

The series expansion of $\arcsin(x)$ is given by 
$$\arcsin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2n}} \cdot \binom{2n}{n} \cdot \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $$
You can use [Stirling approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) to show that $\displaystyle \binom{ 2n}{n}\le \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ for all $n \ge 1 $ and use [$p-$ series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) test to show convergence.

Comment: A comment: it's not clear to me that the notation at the end stands for simultaneous convergence (as per the comparison test) rather than (near-)equality of series.