# Convergent or divergent $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2n+2)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

\begin{align}
  & \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2n+2)}} \\ 
 & \text{ordering} \\ 
 & a_{n}=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2n+2)}=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2n-3)(2n-1)\cdot 1}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2n-2)(2n)(2n+2)}= \\ 
 & \underbrace{\left( 1-\frac{1}{2} \right)\left( 1-\frac{1}{4} \right)...\left( 1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)}_{n\text{ times}}\frac{1}{(2n+2)} \\ 
 & \text{clearly} \\ 
 & \left( 1-\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n}\frac{1}{(2n+2)}\le a_{n}\le \left( 1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)^{n}\frac{1}{(2n+2)} \\ 
 & \text{Root test} \\ 
 & \sqrt[n]{\left( 1-\frac{1}{2} \right)^{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(2n+2)}}\le \sqrt[n]{a_{n}}\le \sqrt[n]{\left( 1-\frac{1}{2n} \right)^{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{(2n+2)}} \\ 
 & n\to \infty  \\ 
 & \frac{1}{2}\le \underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}\le 1 \\ 
 & \text{nothing :(} \\ 
 & \text{Ratio test} \\ 
 & \frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2n-3)(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2n)(2n+2)}\centerdot \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6...(2(n-1)+2)}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5...(2(n-1)-1)}=\frac{2n-1}{2n+2} \\ 
 & \underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n-1}}=1 \\ 
 & \text{nothing again} \\ 
\end{align}

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Raabe's Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html) should work.

Comment: Are you familiar with the $\Gamma$ function ? Please, answer.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164889/why-do-the-endpoints-of-the-maclaurin-series-for-arcsin-converge/165064#165064).  Your series is dominated by the linked one or you can replace $(2N+1)^{-1}$ by $(2N+2)^{-1}$ .

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm not familiar with that,

Comment: @WimC Thanks I will see that answer

Comment: Are you sure the sum starts with $n=0$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the sum can start at $n = 0$ provided we interpret the product of an empty list of number is 1.

Answer (score 4):

An explicit computation is even better. We have:
$$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}=\frac{1}{(2n+2)\,4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}-\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$
hence your series is telescopic and we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4^{N+1}}\binom{2N+2}{N+1}=\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right).$$

In order to prove the last asymptotics, notice that:
$$\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2N}{N}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)^{2N}dx\leq\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{-Nx^2}\,dx\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N}}.$$

Comment: How do you prove the last equality? Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: I have just updated my answer to prove that asymptotics.

Comment: OK Jack D'Aurizio, instead of Stirling's formula, you have used Wallis integrals 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)^{2N}dx=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2N}{N}$$
and the gaussian integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{ 2}.$$
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You may write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots(2n+2)} &=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot 5\cdot6\cdots(2n-1)\cdot 2n}{(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots (2n))^2(2n+2)}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^{n} \cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots n)^2 \cdot (2n+2)}\\
& =\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2 \cdot (2n+2)}\\
& \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}\cdot (2n+2)}\\
& \sim \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}\cdot n^{\Large\frac 32}}, \quad \text{for} \, n \, \text{great}
\end{align}
$$
where we have use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), then you easily conclude to the convergence of the series.