# Limiting behavior of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

I am trying to determine whether $\Gamma(x+iy)\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$.
How should I go about doing it?

I was trying to see if I could get anything from $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$ but although $|\sin z|\rightarrow\infty$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$, I think it does not follow that $\Gamma(z)\rightarrow 0$. Am I right?

Another approach I was trying was a change of variables by letting $u=\ln t$ so that (for $x>0$,) $\Gamma(x+iy)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{xu}e^{-e^{u}}e^{iyu}du$. I have a couple of questions about this. First, is $e^{xu}e^{-e^{u}}$ integrable over the real line? Next, is there something about Fourier transforms that I can use here (perhaps the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a simple estimate:
$$
\begin{align}
|\Gamma(z)|
&=\left|\;\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\;\right|\\
&\le\int_0^\infty t^{\mathrm{Re}(z)-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\Gamma(\mathrm{Re}(z))\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
As CYC mentions, this estimate can be used to show that
$$
|\Gamma(z)|=\frac{|\Gamma(z+1)|}{|z|}\le\frac{|\Gamma(\mathrm{Re}(z+1))|}{|z|}\tag{2}
$$
Which gives the desired decay.

**Polynomial Decay**

In fact, for $z=x+iy$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
|\Gamma(x+iy)|
&=\frac{|\Gamma(z+n)|}{|z(z+1)(z+2)\dots(z+n-1)|}\\[6pt]
&\le\frac{|\Gamma(x+n)|}{|y|^n}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
which gives decay faster than any power of $1/|y|$.

**Exponential Decay**

Using estimate $(3)$ and $\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{n!}\le(n+x)^x$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
e^{\alpha|y|}|\Gamma(x+iy)|
&\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n|y|^n}{n!}\frac{|\Gamma(x+n)|}{|y|^n}\\
&\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\alpha^n(n+x)^x\\
&=C(\alpha,x)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
which converges for $\alpha<1$. Thus, for $\alpha<1$
$$
|\Gamma(x+iy)|\le C(\alpha,x)e^{-\alpha|y|}\tag{5}
$$

**Particular Value**

Since $\Gamma$ is real on the real axis,
$$
\Gamma\left(x-iy\right)=\overline{\Gamma\left(x+iy\right)}\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, applying the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) for $\Gamma$ yields
$$
\left|\Gamma\left(\tfrac12+iy\right)\right|^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh(\pi y)}\tag{7}
$$

Comment: It turns out I can use the inequality in the following way: $|\Gamma(z)|=\frac{|\Gamma(z+1)|}{|z|}\leq\frac{\Gamma(\mathrm{Re}(z)+1)}{|z|} \rightarrow 0$. This gives the result for $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$. Then I can use $\Gamma(z)=\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{z}$ in an inductive argument to get the result for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\leq 0$.

Comment: @CYC: of course! very nice. This same argument shows that for fixed $\mathrm{Re}(z)$, $|\Gamma(z)|$ decays faster than any power of $|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

Use Stirling approximation for the gamma function and see what you get

$$ \Gamma(z+1)\sim\sqrt{2\pi z}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^{z}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

From your identity 
$$\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$
you may indeed deduce :
$$\Gamma(iy)\,\Gamma(-iy)=|\Gamma(iy)|^2=\frac{\pi}{y\,\sinh(\pi y)}$$
observe that 
$$\Gamma(x+iy)\approx (iy)^x\,\Gamma(iy)\quad\text{for}\ |x|\ll |y|$$ 
and conclude that you are right !

Comment: I know how to prove [Gautschi's inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028) on the real line, but how does one prove the last estimate you have?  Usual convexity arguments appear to fail.

Comment: @robjohn: Well starting with $\Gamma(n+1+iy)=(n+iy)\Gamma(n+iy)$, using $n\ll |y|$ and the regularity of $\Gamma$ for $x\approx n$ to conclude I think...

Comment: I couldn't get the second equation myself ($\Gamma(iy)\,\Gamma(-iy)=|\Gamma(iy)|^2=\frac{\pi}{y\,\sinh(\pi y)}$). How is it done?

Comment: @ChungYeongChyuan: You may use : $\Gamma(iy)\,\Gamma(1-iy)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(i\pi y)}$ i.e.  $-iy\,\Gamma(iy)\,\Gamma(-iy)=\frac{\pi}{-i\sinh(\pi y)}\ $ since $\Gamma(1+w)=w\Gamma(w)$ for $w=-iy\ $ and $-i\sin(ix)=\sinh(x)$ as seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Hyperbolic_functions_for_complex_numbers) (use too $\Gamma(\overline{z})=\overline{\Gamma(z)}$).