# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right]^2\cdot\frac{1}{2n+1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

If we know that $I_{n}=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\sin^n(x)\,{\rm d}x$ we need to evaluate:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right]^2\cdot\frac{1}{2n+1}$
( **!!** means double factorial ).

---

Here is all my steps to arrive at a squeeze theorem:

$I_{_{n}}=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot I_{n-2}$, $\forall x\geq 2$. Therefore:

$I_{_{2k}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot (\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2k+1}{2k+2})=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k})$

$I_{_{2k+1}}=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2k+2}{2k+3}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}$

$\Rightarrow I_{2k}\geq I_{2k+1}$ , $\forall x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

$\Rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k})\mid\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k-1}$

$\Rightarrow \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k^2}{4k^2-1}\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$

---

> I don't know how can I arrive at $\left[\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right]^2\cdot\frac{1}{2n+1}$ and after use squeeze theorem.
>
> Is something $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k-1}$ ?
>
> I want to continue with this method, if is something who can help me to finish I'll apreciate.

Comment: I hope dominated convergence theorem would be useful?

Comment: can you show your method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write things in terms of the Gamma function
$$
\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\,\Gamma(\frac12)}{\Gamma(n+\frac12)}
$$
Gautschi's Inequality, proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028), says
$$
n^{1/2}\lt\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+\frac12)}\lt(n+1)^{1/2}
$$
Since $\Gamma(\frac12)=\sqrt\pi$,
$$
\frac{\pi n}{2n+1}\lt\left[\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right]^2\frac1{2n+1}\lt\frac{\pi(n+1)}{2n+1}
$$
Therefore, using the Squeeze Theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\right]^2\frac1{2n+1}=\frac\pi2
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the Wallis formula and [its derivation can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iy9g185qjky8lo/Wallis_formula.pdf?dl=0). Also, note that double factorial is a terrible notation to use and kindly refrain from using it in future.

Comment: @Lucas Did you read the second part on the link? Do not comment without reading it completely.

Comment: the double factorial is often more compact than trying to write the same thing with factorials. I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @robjohn There are much more elegant and clear ways to express double factorial. $n!! = 2^{n/2} (n/2)!$ when $n$ is even and $n!! = \dfrac{n!}{2^{(n-1)/2} ((n-1)/2)!}$. Ofcourse, notions and more important than notations but that doesn't mean we can abuse notations. When you read typically we parse from left to right or right to left, *a single character by character*. Hence, a typical interpretation is $(n!)!$. And an even better notation would be $$\prod_{k =0}^{(n-1)/2} (n-2k) \text{ instead of }n!!$$