# $\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)...(p+n)}{(q+1)(q+2)(q+3)...(q+n)}$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to determine for which values of $p$ and $q$, both greater than $0$, the following series converges: $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)...(p+n)}{(q+1)(q+2)(q+3)...(q+n)}$$

I've tried using the ratio test, comparison test, and I've also tried partial fraction decomposition but I can't get to anything.

Could you give me a hint on how to solve this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What did you get for the ratio ?

Comment: It converges for $q>p+1$, by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: @Lucian Could you show me how did you compare it?

Comment: **Hint:** $(a+1)(a+2)(a+3)\cdots(a+n)=\dfrac{(n+a)!}{a!}$

Comment: Even if a is not an integer?

Comment: Raabe's test: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html

Comment: @mobzopi: Yes. But my advice for you would be to start small, and just see what happens for $q=p$, $q=p+1$, and $q=p+2$. The first will yield an infinite sum of ones; the second will be a $($divergent$)$ [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), and the third a $($convergent$)$ [*p*-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have probably noticed, the ratio test is useless here. The next thing to try when the ratio test fails is the [Raabe-Duhame test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Raabe-Duhamel.27s_test). In our case this amounts to computing the following limit: $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} n(\frac {q+n+1} {p+n+1} -1) = \lim \limits _{n \to \infty} \frac {(q-p)n} {p+n+1} = q-p$. Now, if $q-p < 1$ the series diverges and if $q-p>1$ the series converges. If $q-p=1$ then the Raabe-Duhamel test fails, but in this case the series becomes $\sum \frac {p+1} {p+1+n}$. Since $p \geq 0$, the series has the same behaviour as the series $\sum \frac 1 n$ which is divergent.

Therefore the series converges only if $q-p>1$.

Comment: (+1) It is also interesting to compute the explicit value of the series under the assumption $q>p+1>0$. I did it through the Beta function, but maybe we can achieve the same by partial fraction decomposition and telescopic sums.

Answer (score 5):

We have:
$$S(p,q)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(p+n)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p+1)}{(q+n)\cdot\ldots\cdot(q+1)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma(p+n+1)\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(q+n+1)\Gamma(p+1)}\tag{1}$$
but in virtue of the Euler product for the $\Gamma$ function (or by its log-convexity encoded in the [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function/103028#103028)) we have:
$$\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z)}=\Theta(z^\alpha)\tag{2}$$
as $z\to +\infty$, hence the series is converging for $q>p+1>0$ by the p-test.

Moreover, in such a case:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}S(p,q)&=&\frac{\Gamma(q+1)}{\Gamma(p+1)\Gamma(q-p)}\sum_{n\geq 1}B(p+n+1,q-p)\\&=&\frac{1}{B(p+1,q-p)}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{p+n}(1-x)^{q-p-1}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{B(p+1,q-p)}\int_{0}^{1}x^{p+1}(1-x)^{q-p-2}\,dx\\[1em]&=&\frac{B(p+2,q-p-1)}{B(p+1,q-p)}=\color{red}{\frac{(p+1)}{q-(p+1)}}.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: (+1) Beat me by seconds! However, [Gautschi's Inequalty](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028) might be useful, too.

Comment: @robjohn: you are clearly right, I am adding your link to my answer to make it more complete. Do you mind?

Comment: Of course not. Explanation is the purpose, and citation is the validation, of the answers here.

Comment: What if $p=-1$ and $q=0$?

Comment: @AlexM. In order to avoid poles of the $\Gamma$ function, $p>-1$ is also required.

Comment: My mistake: $p>0$ by hypothesis. Otherwise, the series would have been convergent for integer values of $p<0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think lucian is right.

Rewrite all as follows:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (p+n)!}{p!} \frac{q!}{(q+n)!}$
and let $q=p+k$ the fact p has to be less than q is obvious.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (p+n)!}{p!} \frac{q!}{(q+n)!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod _{j=1}^k \biggl(\frac {p+j}{p+n+j} \biggr) \leq  (p+k)^k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^k \frac{ 1}{p+n+j}$
$ \leq (p+k)^k \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(p+n+1)^k}$
and now you have your classical $1/n^i$, and the answer is the one given by lucian.

Comment: Please note that $p$ and $q$ are not necessarily natural numbers, therefore it might not make sense to speak about their factorials. A proof involving the $\Gamma$ function has been given above by @Jack D'Aurizio.