# Which theorems in the Gamma Function are important?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

I'm interested in the Special Functions especially the Gamma Function. I decided to write a Bachelor Thesis about it but I do not know what kind of theorem(s) in the Gamma Function that is (are) very important or popular. Can you suggest some ideas?

Comment: That it is a proper extension?

Comment: I would start with whatever Emil Artin thought was interesting about the Gamma function. See Rosen's [Expositions by Emil Artin](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/hmath-30) for a copy of his writeup.

Comment: Julian Havil's *Gamma: Exploring Euler's Constant* contains much that will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some milestones:

- The Bohr-Mollerup theorem;
- The integral representation for the $\Gamma$ function;
- Euler's and Weierstrass products.

You may further investigate the Wallis product and [Gautchi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function), the Laplace transform of $x^u$ (and the bound for the least quadratic non-residue [given by Ankeny](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969420) through that technique, very interesting), problems related with the digamma function, relations between some values of the $\Gamma$ function and some elliptic integrals, irrationality or trascendence of some values of the $\Gamma$ function and much more. It is a very nice topic.