# $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(1 - (k+1)^{-2}) = 1$?

Tags: calculus, telescopic-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(1 - (k+1)^{-2}) = 1$$

Where $\ln_2$ is the binary log(log base 2).

I assume this can be done by some sort of telescoping ?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(1 - (k+1)^{-2}) = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(k^2 + 2k) - \ln_2(k^2 + 2k +1)$$

I guess I am doing it wrong ?
I can go further,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(k^2 + 2k) - \ln_2(k^2 + 2k +1)= \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} \ln_2(k) +\ln_2(k + 2) - 2 \ln_2(k + 1) = 1$$

Now if I exponentiate both sides I have a valid expression for $2$.
So I know it is true, but Im not being efficient here I think.

Comment: Found it : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676164/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-ln-left-fracnn2n12-right-converges

Comment: Then why not close/delete? (Wrong sign BTW)

Comment: Closed as duplicate. The question has an answer, see the link.