# Limit of $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ when $x\to 1^-$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, riemann-zeta

I am trying to understand if

$$\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x}}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$$ is convergent for $x\to 1^-$. Any help?

---

**Update:** Given the insightful comments below, it is clear it is not converging, hence the actual question now is to find

> $$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

Comment: Not sure but Binomial theorem might help u..

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, thank you !

Comment: @Jasser: No, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: And... what did you try?

Comment: I used $\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}x^k$. And $\sqrt{\pi}=\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$. Coefficients of $x^k$ have to be checked..

Comment: Are you sure $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x}}$ is not meant to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}$? As you have it at the moment the coefficients of $x^n$ differ by a factor of approx $\sqrt2$ for large $n$.

Comment: @almagest: I am sure - at the moment. But of course if my term is unlimited (but that has to be proofed), I am interested in an alternative.

Comment: I think the stirling formula helps.

Comment: Notice $\displaystyle\;\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}} = {\rm Li}_{1/2}(x)$ where ${\rm Li}_s(x)$ is the 
[Polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). We have
$${\rm Li}_s(e^\mu) = \Gamma(1-s)(-\mu)^{s-1} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\zeta(s-k)}{k!} \mu^k
\quad\text{ for }\quad
|\mu| < 2\pi,\; s \ne 1, 2, 3,\ldots
$$
This implies
$$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right) = -\zeta(1/2) \approx
1.460354508809586812889499...
$$

Comment: @achillehui: please post it as an answer!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio technically, this doesn't answer the question as it is not a proof.

Comment: @achillehui: well, it is a proof to the real question :)

Comment: @achillehui: Thank you very much for the result, I agree with Jack D'Aurizio.

Comment: @achillehui I took the liberty of posting a solution that relied on the methodology you outlined in your comment.  I hope that you don't mind.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't mind. In any event, I never have the intention to post that as an answer because I don't want to justify the asymptotic expansion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comment posted by @Achillehui, we recognize that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ is a series representation of the polylogarithm function $\text{Li}_{1/2}(x)$, for $|x|<1$.

An alternative series representation ([SEE HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Series_representations)) of $\text{Li}_{1/2}(x)$ is given by

$$\text{Li}_{1/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-\log(x)}}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\zeta(1/2-k)}{k!}\log^k(x) \tag 1$$

for $|x|<e^{2\pi}$.

Note that we can expand the logarithm function around $x=1$ as

$$\begin{align}
-\log(x)&=(1-x)\left(1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(x-1)^{k-1}}{k}\right)\\\\
&=(1-x)\left(1+O\left((x-1)\right)\right) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Using $(2)$ in $(1)$, we obtain

$$\text{Li}_{1/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}++\zeta(1/2)+O\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(1/2-k)}{k!}\log^k(x) \tag 3$$

Finally, it is easy to see from $(3)$ that

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=-\zeta(1/2)$$

And we are done!

Comment: (+1) How to prove that asymptotic expansion, however, is a tougher problem than the OP's one :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Jack, that is for certain.  First, we start with an integral representation of $\text{Li}_s(z)$ and deform the Hankel contour.  Then, we evaluate that integral as a series of residues.  Finally, we fold the series, expand the binomial coefficients, change the order of summation, carry out the inner sum, and arrive at the coveted expression. -Mark

Answer (score 7):

In order to make user90369's (excellent and elementary) answer a real answer, we have to show that
 $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{\pi}\tag{1}$$
or:
$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} (1-x)\sum_{m\geq 2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{m-n}}\right)x^m=\pi\tag{2} $$
but that follows from the same argument it is usually exploited to prove [Hilbert's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_inequality), namely that for large $m$s,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{m-n}}=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{m}}\sqrt{1-\frac{n}{m}}}\approx \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}=\pi.\tag{3} $$
If we set $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $h(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}$, $(1)$ alone is not enough to ensure that $h(x)-f(x)$ is bounded in a left neighbourhood of $x=1$. However, the study of the Taylor coefficients is:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}h(x)-f(x)&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)x^n\\&=&\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)x^n\\&\ll&\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}\ll 1\tag{1bis}\end{eqnarray*} $$
by [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function). Now we may exploit an analytic continuation.
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{\sqrt{n}}+2\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}=g(x)+\sqrt{2}\,f(x^2)$$
hence:
$$ g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{\sqrt{n}} = f(x)-\sqrt{2}\,f(x^2)\tag{4}$$
while $h(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1-x}}$ fulfills:
$$ h(x)-\sqrt{2}\,h(x^2) = h(x)\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+x}}\right) \tag{5}$$
hence:

> $$\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(h(x)-f(x)\right) &=& \frac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}}\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left[h(x)-\sqrt{2}\,h(x^2)-f(x)+\sqrt{2}\,f(x^2)\right]\\&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\lim_{x\to 1^-}g(x)\\&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}=\color{red}{-\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}. \tag{6}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: To square, interesting , thank you !

Comment: Leakages from a talented mathematician...

Comment: So your (1) to (3) should be deleted... I dont see any connection between them and the real solution...And is the zeta function continuous at 1/2, I'm not very familiar with zeta functions...

Comment: @Yongyong: $(1)$ is necessary to make $(3),(4),(5)$ actually work, and to prove $(1)$ I used $(2)$ and $(3)$, so no, they cannot be deleted. And if you are not that confident with the $\zeta$ function, you may simply ignore the very last expression: the answer is given by a (slowly) convergent series.

Comment: Jack, can one not write $f(x)-\sqrt{2}f(x^2)=g(x)$ and $h(x)-\sqrt{2}h(x^2)=h(x)\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+x}}\right)$ without appealing to $(1)$?  I am missing the connection here also.

Comment: We need that $h(x)-f(x)$ is bounded in a left neighbourhood of $1$, otherwise the first step of $(6)$ does not hold.

Comment: It is obvious that we cannot replace $\pi$ by *any* constant and still have the same answer.

Comment: Indeed, $(1)$ shows that $f/h$ is bounded near $1^-$ with limit equal to $1$.  So, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $1-\delta <x<1$ implies $-\epsilon h(x)<f(x)-h(x)<\epsilon h(x)$.  And for fixed $x<1$, $f-h$ is bounded.  However, inasmuch as $h(x)\to \infty$ as $x\to 1^-$, how does this show that  $\lim_{x\to 1^-}(f(x)-h(x))$ exists?  That is, the limit of the difference is not implied by the limit of the ratio.

Comment: @Dr.MV: that can be done by comparing the Taylor coefficients of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$, i.e. $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, as already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yes, the coefficients are asymptotically $1/n^{3/2}$ and so the series of the difference converges for $x\to 1^-$.  Given that, what does $(1)$ provide in addition?  Apology if this seems trivial.

Comment: @Dr.MV: thinking about it, nothing. It is just an alternative proof of $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=1$$ or Wallis product.

Comment: Or $$\sum_{n+m=N}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{2m}{m}=4^N.$$ There is a plethora of equivalent, interesting results hidden there.

Comment: Jack, thanks for verifying that.  And in reviewing this, $(1)$, by itself, does not seem to provide the proof of the limit of $f-h$.  The analysis of the coefficients does.  So, perhaps it might be better to begin with that analysis, which then permits the ensuing development.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: you are right as usual. I am going to update the answer.

Comment: your result $(1)$ reminds me of the formula $$\lim_{x \to 1^{-1}}\sqrt{1 - x}(x + x^{4} + x^{9} + \cdots) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx$$ +1

Comment: Is it possible to link the result $(1)$ to the formula I quote in my previous comment? ( i think they look very similar so I was hoping for a connection).

Answer (score 2):

$f(x):=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}$

$g(x):= \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x}}-f(x)$

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}=f(x)-\sqrt{2}f(x^2)$ is convergent for $x\uparrow 1$ .

=>

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^k}{\sqrt{k}}+\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x}}-\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x^2}}= g(x)-\sqrt{2}g(x^2)$.

For $x\uparrow 1$ we get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=(1-\sqrt{2})g(1)$.

Therefore is the limit $g(1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

EDIT: See above, it's not $\sqrt{2\pi}$, it's $\sqrt{\pi}$

Thank you all for your efforts!

EDIT 2: $g(1)=-\zeta(\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: When $\sqrt{2\pi}$ really comes into play?

Comment: A very good question ! I only assume, that $g(1)$ is $<\infty$, but than it works. Why ?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: It seems to be that I don't proof, THAT there is a limit. But IF a limit exits, THEN its $g(1)$. Therefore my question is still opened, you are right.

Comment: I just added a proof of the "missing part" in your argument. Now your answer with my prologue gives an elementary alternative to achille hui's technique (asymptotics for $\text{Li}_s$).

Comment: I know, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using the binomial series you know that $\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1-x}}=\sqrt{2\pi}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2}\\k\end{pmatrix}(-x)^k=\sqrt{2\pi}+\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k)!}{4^k(k!)^2}x^k$. Using Stirling's formula you know that $\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{(2k)!}{4^kk!}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4^k}(1+\epsilon_k)\frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2k)}(\frac{2k}{e})^{2k}}{(\sqrt{2\pi k}(\frac{k}{e})^{k})^2}=(1+\epsilon_k)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{k}}$, where $\epsilon_k\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Now compare this to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$, for $k$ large enough, the kompnents of the sum is for instance larger than $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{k}}$, Then the sum is $\geq C+\sum_{k>N}\frac{1}{3\sqrt{k}}x^k$. The right hand side goes to infinity as $x\rightarrow 1$ form left side.

---

I think the problem would be more interesting if we have $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the first komponent, then it seems that one should modify $\epsilon_k$ to obtain the rate, but this not clear for me, at least this is not readable from the given Stirling's formula.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!