# Log-convexity of the p-norms of a fixed function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm stuck on part of a real analysis problem; unfortunately, I'm stuck with how to start it.

Suppose $f \in L^p(X)$ for all $p$ satisfying $r < p < s$.  Let $\phi(p) = ||f||_p^p$.  Show that $\phi$ is log-convex on $(r,s)$.

Other parts of the problem ask for continuity of $\phi$, the connectedness (i.e. convexity) of the set of values $p$ at which $\phi$ is finite, that $\phi(p) \rightarrow ||f||_\infty$ and the inclusion $L_r \cap L_s \subset L_p$, all of which I have done, but I am just totally stuck on this other part.  Indeed, I can't even show that $\phi$ is convex, much less log-convex.

This problem is presented right after Holder's Inequality, so it should not use any advanced machinery or differentiability.  I could really use some help, here!

Thanks!

Comment: It's immediate from Holder's inequality, if you diddle the p's and q's properly.  If $t+(1-t)=1$ then $1/t$ and $1/(1-t)$ are conjugate exponents...

Comment: Haha, oh man, this is such a simple observation that I have never made!  Thanks, I will remember this for sure now lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $t_1,t_2\in(r,s)$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$.  Then we have
$$\log\phi(\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2)=\log\left(\int|f|^{\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2}\right) $$
By Holder's inequality, we have 
\begin{align*} \log\left(\int|f|^{\lambda t_1+(1-\lambda)t_2}\right)&
\leq\log\left[ \left( \int |f|^{t_1}\right)^\lambda \left( \int |f|^{t_2}\right)^{1-\lambda}\right]\\
&=\lambda\log\left( \int |f|^{t_1} \right)+(1-\lambda)\log\left( \int |f|^{t_2} \right)\\
&=\lambda\log\phi(t_1)+(1-\lambda)\log\phi(t_2) 
\end{align*}
and therefore $\log\phi$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks man!  Much appreciated.