# Is it true that the function $\varphi (p)=\int { { |f| }^{ p } } d\mu $ is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu )$ a measure speace, f measurable function, $E=\left\{ { p\ge 1 }|{ \int { { |f| }^{ p }d\mu  } <\infty  } \right\} $ and $\varphi (p)=\int { { |f| }^{ p } } d\mu $ then $\varphi (p)$ is continuous at the interior of E?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can prove that $E$ is an interval, and that $\log\varphi$ is convex in the interior of $E$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880656/log-convexity-of-the-p-norms-of-a-fixed-function

Comment: I've already proved that $log(\varphi)$ is convex, but how can i use that for prove that $\varphi$ is continuous ?

Comment: @PacoFrancisco, convex in an open interval $\implies$ continuous. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258511/proof-of-every-convex-function-is-continuous.