# Show that for a fixed $q$ the Beta function $B(p,q)$ is log convex.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, beta-function

I want to show that for a fixed $q$ the Beta function $B(p,q)$ is log convex. I tried to show that the second derivative of the Beta function with respect to $p$ is larger than zero, i.e. that:

\begin{equation}
\partial_p^2 \log(\int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1} dt) = \partial_p(\frac{\int_0^1t^{p-1}\log(t)(1-t)^{q-1} dt}{\int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1} dt}) = \\ \frac{(\int_0^1t^{p-1}\log^2(t)(1-t)^{q-1} dt)(\int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1} dt) - (\int_0^1t^{p-1}\log(t)(1-t)^{q-1} dt)^2}{(\int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1} dt)^2} \geq 0
\end{equation}
where I used the Leibniz integral rule twice.

So I need to show that
\begin{equation}
(\int_0^1t^{p-1}\log^2(t)(1-t)^{q-1} dt)(\int_0^1t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q-1} dt) - (\int_0^1t^{p-1}\log(t)(1-t)^{q-1} dt)^2 \geq 0
\end{equation}

But I am unsure on how to proceed - I don't know how to get rid of the integrals in this expression. Could you please help me?

Comment: Try Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: For any measure space $(A,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ and measurable function $h\geq0$, the set $E=\{p\geq-:\int_X h^p\,d\mu<\infty\}$ is convex. If $E$ has interior then the map $p\mapsto \log\Big(\int_Xh^p\,d\mu\Big)$ is convex. [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1880656/121671). I your case $X=[0,1]$, $\mathscr{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu(dx)=x(1-x)^{1-p}\,dx$.