# Two problems on real number series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Consider the series:

$$a) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{ \prod_{k=1}^n \ (1+\sin\frac{1}{2k})}$$
$$b) \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{ \prod_{k=1}^n \ (1+\tan\frac{3}{2k})}$$

Showing that these two are convergent (and absolutely convergent) it's no big deal for  $a\in R^*$. But I couldn't figure out how to solve it when $a=1$. My guess is that the general term has to be brought to another form. And that is my question: how to prove convergence when $a=1$.

Thanks for helping with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove the following asymptotics: $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{2k}\right)\sim\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)\sim 2\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \tag{1}$$
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\tan\frac{3}{2k}\right)\sim\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{3}{2k}\right)\sim \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\frac{n^3}{\pi}} \tag{2}$$
through [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) to get that the first series is divergent at $a=1$ while the second one is convergent, by the $p$-test. [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html) is another efficient alternative.