# Prove that there is $c >0$ such that $\int_0^1f^2dx \leq c \int_0^1 f'^2 dx$ for all $f \in C^1$ with $f(x+1) = f(x)$ and $\int_0^1f(x)dx = 0$.

Tags: continuity, problem-solving, functional-equations, riemann-integration

> Prove that there is a constant $c >0$ such that $\int_0^1f(x)^2 dx \leq c \int_0^1 f'(x)^2 dx$ for all continuously differentiable function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(x+1) = f(x)$ and $\int_0^1f(x) dx = 0$.

I am not sure how to go about this problem. I was thinking of expressing $f$ as a Fourier series, especially as we have the periodicity condition. I was also thinking of using the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but it was not immediate how we could use the DCT.

I would appreciate some hints. Thank you

Comment: This is quite easy using the $L^{2}$ theory of Fourier series. Just write the Fourier coefficients of $f$ in terms of those of $f$ and use Parseval's identity for both $f$ and $f'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^1f(x) dx = 0$ implies there exists $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.
Let $g(x)$ be the translation of $f(x)$ by $x_0$, i.e., $g(x)= f(x+x_0)$.
Since $f(x+1)=f(x)$, we have
$\int_0^1f(x)^2 dx =\int_0^1g(x)^2 dx$
and $ \int_0^1 f'(x)^2 dx=\int_0^1 g'(x)^2 dx$.
It is enough to prove the same conclusion for $g(x)$, which is also continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$.

---

Since $g(0)=0$, we have the first equality below. The first inequality is Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.
$$g(x)^2=\left(\int_0^x1\cdot g'(t)\,dt\right)^2 \le \int_0^x1^2\,dt \int_0^x g'(t)^2\,dt \le x \int_0^1 g'(t)^2\,dt,$$

$$\int_0^1g(x)^2\,dx \le \int_0^1 x\,dx \int_0^1g'(t)^2\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1g'(t)^2\,dt.$$

We obtain constant $\frac12$.

---

Since $g(0)=g(1)=0$, we can apply [the second version of Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions#Second_version) to $g(x)$.

$$\int_0^1g(x)^2dx \le \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^1g'(t)^2 dt.$$

We obtain constant $\frac1{\pi^2}$, which is the best possible.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164126/showing-an-inequality-on-a-definite-integral?noredirect=1) are proofs for the Wirtinger's inequality.

Comment: The condition "$f(x+1)=f(x)$" is not needed for constant $\frac 12$