# For a polynomial $P_k(t)$ prove that $C_k \le \frac{\pi}{2}(k+1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, polynomials, definite-integrals

> For , $k\in \mathbb N$ , let $$P_k(t)=C_k\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^k \text{ , } t\in [-\pi,\pi]$$where $C_k\in \mathbb R$ is choosen in such a way that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_k(t)\,dt=1.$$
>
> Then prove that $\displaystyle C_k \le \frac{\pi}{2}(k+1)$ for all $k\in \Bbb N$.

We have , $P_k(t)=C_k\cos^{2k}\left(t/2\right)$. Then , from $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P_k(t)\,dt=1.$$
$$\implies 2C_k\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{2k}(z)\,dz=\pi$$
$$\implies C_k=\frac{\pi.k!}{\sqrt{\pi}.\Gamma \left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}$$
Then , how I can proceed to complete the proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may conclude through [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) or the log-convexity of the $\Gamma$ function that follows from the [Bohr-Mollereup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem). You are requesting that
$$ C_k \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1+\cos x}{2}\right)^k\,dx = 2\pi $$ 
or
$$ C_k = \left[\frac{1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k}\right]^{-1} $$
so it is enough to show that
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\leq \frac{k+1}{4^k}\binom{2k}{k} $$
where the RHS is related with the reciprocal [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Comment: From my last line of my question we can write $\displaystyle C_k=\frac{\pi.\Gamma {(k+1)}}{\sqrt{\pi}.\Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}<\sqrt{\pi}.(k+1)^{1/2}<\pi(k+1)$ , using [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) , and as $k\in \mathbb N$. Is it correct ?

Comment: @S717717: absolutely, yes.

Comment: Then Wallis product is not needed.

Comment: @S717717: I agree, it just gives another way for reaching the same conclusion.

Comment: Yes. Thank you... Gautschi's inequality ,  Bohr-Mollereup theorem ,  Wallis product all were unknown to me. I've just heard these things from you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

$$ C_k=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi} k!}{\Gamma (k+\frac12)}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}\: k(k-1)(k-2)\dots 1}{\sqrt\pi\:((k-1)+\frac12)((k-2)+\frac12)\dots (1+\frac12) \frac12 }=\\
=2k \dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2(k-1)})(1+\frac{1}{2(k-2)})\dots (1+\frac{1}{2})}<
2k \dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{2(k-1)})^{k-1}}=2k(1-\dfrac{1}{2k-1})^{k-1}<\\
<2k(1-\dfrac{1}{2k})^{k-1}<\dfrac{2k}{\sqrt e}(1-\dfrac1{2k})^{-1}<\dfrac{2k}{\sqrt e}\dfrac{6}{5}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}(k+1) $$ for $k>2$