# Show $0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}n!}{n^{1/2}(2n-1)!!}<\infty$.

Tags: limits

I want to show that
$$0<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}n!}{n^{1/2}(2n-1)!!}<\infty$$
By induction, the sequence is bounded above by $2$ and decreasing, so by monotone convergence, it has a finite limit. I'm stuck showing that the limit is positive. Plugging in big numbers makes me guess it converges to $\sqrt{\pi}$, but I'm not sure how to show it is bounded below by a positive number.

Comment: maybe $(2n)!=(2n-1)!!\cdot n!2^{n}$ and stirling aproximation is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\left( 2n-1\right)!!=\frac{\left( 2n\right)!}{n!2^n}$, you seek $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^24^n}{\left( 2n\right)!\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\pi n^{2n+1}4^ne^{-2n}}{2^{2n+1/2}\sqrt{2\pi}n^{2n+1}e^{-2n}}=\sqrt{\pi}$$(as you guessed), using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation) $n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}$. The ratio of these expressions is $\approx e^{1/\left( 12n\right)}$, so the error $\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: apologies for the simple question, I wasn't familiar with Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$$ \frac{2^n n!}{\sqrt{n}(2n-1)!!} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2k}}$$
whose square is given by
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^2}=\frac{4}{n\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)} $$
that boils down to:
$$ 4\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}\right). $$
Since $\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}$ is convergent, the limit as $n\to +\infty$ of the previous product is a finite positive number. This proves the claim. *Which number* is given by the Weierstrass product for the cosine function, for instance.

As an alternative approach, it is enough to write $\frac{2^n n!}{\sqrt{n}(2n-1)!!}$ in terms of the $\Gamma$ function and exploit [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function). That instantly gives the value of the limit, too.

Comment: I sort of flirted with this idea on my own, except that I wasn't able to reach the conclusion that the product converges to a positive number. What does the convergence of the series have to do with it?

Comment: @user363464: it is the very definition of *convergent product*. $\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+a_n)$ is convergent iff $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: the definition of convergent product that I had in mind was that the sequence of finite products converge, but I see that your comment is a theorem in my textbook (although much further ahead of the part I'm working on).

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test gives

$$\lim_{+\infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}=$$

$$2\lim_{+\infty}\frac {(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)!!}=0 $$

for enough great $n $,

$$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}<k <1$$

thus $(a_n) $ converges to 0.

Comment: Are you really sure that the limit of the ratio is $0$?