# Proof for a peculiar Product Identity:

Tags: proof-writing, gamma-function, products

When I was trying to evaluate a definite integral (given below the question for those who're curious), I came across a paper of Ramanujan pertaining to the evaluation of the very same integral. Amidst the paper's proofs, Ramanujan mentions the following:

---

*It's easy to see that*:
$$\prod^{n=\alpha}_{n=1}\left\{\frac{\left(1+\frac{\alpha+2\beta}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{\beta+2\alpha}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{n}\right)^3\left(1+\frac{\beta}{n}\right)^3}\right\}=\frac{[\Gamma(1+\alpha)\Gamma(1+\beta)]^3}{\Gamma(1+\alpha+2\beta)\Gamma(1+\beta+2\alpha)}$$

**Right. So how do I go about proving this?**

---

---

---

Note: The integral I was attempting to evaluate: 
$$\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\tan^{-1}x^3}{e^{4\pi x}-1}dx$$

Comment: Is the upper limit of the product $\alpha$ or $\infty$?

Comment: If the upper limit is $\alpha$, just plug in $\alpha=\beta=1$ and we get that $\frac14=\frac1{36}$. If the upper limit is $\infty$, use either of the answers given so far.

Comment: In some older textbooks the $\infty$ symbol is written with the right loop open and that may look like a Greek $\alpha $. The identity involves upper limit as $\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the infinite product formula for $\Gamma$:
$$\frac1{\Gamma(z)}=ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}$$
which yields
$$\frac1{\Gamma(z+1)}=\frac1{z\Gamma(z)}=e^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-z/n}$$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the upper limit of the product is supposed to be $\infty$.

**Hint:**

By [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028/13854), $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}{m^\alpha\,\Gamma(m+1)}=1$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1{m^\alpha}\prod_{n=1}^m\left(1+\frac{\alpha}n\right)
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1{m^\alpha}\prod_{n=1}^m\left(\frac{\color{#C00}{n+\alpha}}{\color{#090}{n}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1{m^\alpha}\color{#C00}{\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\alpha+1\right)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}}\color{#090}{\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma\left(m+1\right)}}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\frac{\Gamma\left(m+\alpha+1\right)}{m^\alpha\,\Gamma(m+1)}\\
&=\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Upper limit is alpha

Comment: @Kugelblitz: then the equation is not true.

Comment: Agreed. +1 @rob