# what is the value x if x factorial equals zero? (x!=0)

Tags: functions, factorial

to avoid confusion: when I'm talking about x factorial I'm talking about the factorial extension to the real (and complex) numbers, not just the naturals.
(because obviously x isn't natural)

Comment: Do you talk about gamma function? There are no zeroes.

Comment: So you are basically talking about the equation $\Gamma(z+1) = 0$ ?

Comment: As @sigmabe says. Take a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to convince yourself.

Comment: There exist many extensions to the factorials. Are you sure you mean the gamma function?

Comment: to all of you, yes i mean the gamma function

Comment: Why do you think this should have solutions? What did you try to approach the question?

Comment: @Did just out of curiosity

Comment: I suspect there are no solutions under the Gamma function due to Logarithmic Convexity.

Comment: @tomsharon "just out of curiosity" You might not realize it, but this comment addresses neither of the two questions in my comment.

Comment: @DId "What did you try to approach the question" i approached it out of curiosity "Why do you think this should have solutions" i dont know if there are any i was just curios if there ware

Comment: @tomsharon: Did's question was _what_ you tried, not _why_ you tried it, though. (For the record, in my opinion this doesn't look like a question where we _should_ be asking "what have you tried", since it is exceedingly unlikely to be a homework problem).

Comment: Still not answering the query. I am asking for the tries you made to solve the question, if any (and I am beginning to suspect that I know the answer to the query, alas).

Comment: @HenningMakholm The thing is that one cannot "fall on" such a question without having read/heard about Gamma and the like. And *about that*, we know nothing.

Comment: @Did i tried to find a real solution and obviously there are none, as for complex solutions i'm not sure

Comment: If your question is about Gamma function, it should probably be tagged ([tag:gamma-function]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)-\frac{z}{k}\right]
&=\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(1+z)}\right)-zH_{n-1}\\
&=\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(1+z)}\right)-z\log(n)-z\gamma+O\!\left(\frac{z}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, and using [Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028), we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left[\log\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)-\frac{z}{k}\right]
=-\log(\Gamma(1+z))-z\gamma
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(1+z)}=e^{z\gamma}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-\frac{z}{k}}
$$
The product on the right hand side converges for all $z$ and is $0$ at the negative integers.

Thus, $\frac1{\Gamma(1+z)}$ is an entire function and $\Gamma(1+z)=z!$ is never $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(z)$ is never zero for any complex $z$. (Zero is the only complex number that is not in the range, though).

Therefore, if you let $x!$ mean $\Gamma(x+1)$ for $x\notin \mathbb Z$, then the equation $x!=0$ has no solutions either.

Comment: What's with the community wiki on this one?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: It's basically just repeating information that was already posted as comments.

Comment: Ah, okay${}~{}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x!=\Gamma(x+1)$$
$$\text{limit}_{n\to\infty} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-n)=0\qquad n=\text{positive integer}$$
Back to factorial :
$$\text{limit}_{n\to\infty} (-\frac{1}{2}-n)!=0\qquad n=\text{positive integer}$$
The improperly so called "solution" of the equation $\quad x!=0\quad$ is not finite :
$$x=-\frac{1}{2}-n\qquad n\to\infty$$