# Find sum to infinite terms of the series $S=\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4.7}{5.8}+\frac{4.7.10}{5.8.11}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Find sum to infinity terms of the series $$S=\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4.7}{5.8}+\frac{4.7.10}{5.8.11}+\cdots$$

My Try:

we have $$1+S=1+\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4.7}{5.8}+\frac{4.7.10}{5.8.11}+\cdots$$

now $$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}+\cdots $$  So comparing we get

$$nx=\frac{4}{5}$$ and

$$\frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2}=\frac{7}{10}$$

solving for $x$ and $n$ we get

$$n=\frac{-16}{19}$$ and $$x=\frac{-19}{20}$$

Hence

$$1+S=(1+x)^n=20^{\frac{16}{19}}$$

$$S=20^{\frac{16}{19}}-1$$

Is this alright?

Comment: Apparently, $S=\infty$ because the series diverges:  $$\prod_{k=1}^n\,\frac{3k+1}{3k+2}=\frac{2^{2/3}\,\Gamma(5/6)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\,\frac{\Gamma(n+4/3)}{\Gamma(n+5/3)} \approx \frac{2^{2/3}\,\Gamma(5/6)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\sqrt[3]{n}}$$
for large positive integers $n$.

Comment: Unless you perhaps miss something like the factor $\frac{1}{n!}$ for the $n$-th term, then you will get a generalized hypergeometric series $$1+S={_1}F_1\left(\frac{4}{3};\frac{5}{3};1\right)\approx 2.28616\,.$$

Comment: The comparison with $(1+x)^n$ is incorrect. Even if the first two terms match some $x$ and $n$, there's no guarantee that the third term will match.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  How is this question a duplicate of the link you gave?

Comment: Is it possible to atleast sum to $n$ terms

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{n\geq 1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+1}{3k+2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^{2/3} \,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{5}{6}\right)\, \Gamma\left(\tfrac{4}{3}+n\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\tfrac{5}{3}+n\right)} $$
is divergent by [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) and the p-test: the main term of such series behaves like $\frac{C}{n^{1/3}}$.