# Does the given series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\prod_{j=1}^k\frac{2j-1}{2j+2}\right)$$ converge?

I am supposed to use the theorem below:

> Theorem: let $x_k>0 \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. If there exists $r<1 $ such that $$\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}<r$$ when  $k\geq k_0\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k$ converges.

What I have tried:

$$\frac{x_{k+1}}{x_{k}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\cdot{}\frac{3}{6}\cdot{}\frac{5}{8}\cdot{}\dots \cdot(2k+1)}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot{}\frac{3}{6}\cdot{}\frac{5}{8}\cdot{}\dots \cdot(2k+4)}=\frac{(2k+1)}{(2k+4)}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{2k})}{(1+\frac{2}{k})}$$this is where I got stuck.

Comment: The ratio test failed you. Are you sure this is the only one you can use?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to use the theorem stated above.

Comment: The ratio test can't give any conclusion on the convergence if the limit of the ratio for $k \to \infty$ is $1$, which seems to be the case here. So, using this method, your answer would be "there's no way to know if the series converges or not"

Comment: @YuriyS how did you find that the series diverges? I think that it doesn't - see below.

Comment: @1likeMaths the lest two terms in your huge fraction should be $\dfrac{2k+1}{2k+4}$, shouldn't they?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, I have made a mistake when writing the series, so my comment was wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extension of the ratio test, [called Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe's_test), states that *in case the ratio test is inconclusive because the limit is $1$*, if $$\lim_{k\to \infty} k\left(\left|\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}\right|-1\right)=R>1$$
then the series absolutely converges.

In your case, $R=\dfrac{3}{2}>1.$

*Note that the fraction here is $\dfrac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}$ instead of $\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}$.*

Answer (score 0):

As already remarked, it is convergent by Raabe's test. As an alternative, one may use [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98348/how-do-you-prove-gautschis-inequality-for-the-gamma-function) and the $p$-test. Additionally the value of the series can be computed through [Euler's Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html):

$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\Gamma(k+2)}=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 1}B\left(k+\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k\geq 1}x^{k-1/2}\sqrt{1-x}\,dx\tag{1}$$
and the RHS equals:
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\,dx =\frac{2}{\pi}B\left(\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\large 1}.\tag{2}$$