# How to derive this series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> The function $\dfrac1{1-x}$, equal to $$1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots,$$ can also be developed according to the series $$1 + \frac{x}{1 + x} + \frac{1\cdot2\cdot x^2}{(1 + x)(1 + 2x)} + \frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot x^3}{(1 + x)(1 + 2x)(1 + 3x)} + \cdots $$ when $x$ is positive and smaller than $1$.

I know the first series and it is easy to obtain it. But the second series is strange. It is not a power series, not a Taylor series. How does one obtain this series?

Comment: The boxed sum looks to be $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n!\cdot x^n}{\prod\limits_{m=0}^n(1+mx)}.$$  Can you make use of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series you are asking about is
$$ S(x) \!:=\! 1 \!+\! \frac{x}{1\!+\!x} \!+\!
 \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot x^2}{(1\!+\!x)(1\!+\!2x)} \!+\!
 \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot x^3}{(1\!+\!x)(1\!+\!2x)(1\!+\!3x)}
 \!+\! \cdots. \tag{1} $$
One of the first things to do in such a series is to find the
ratio of consecutive terms which gives the sequence
$$ \frac{x}{1+x},\;\; \frac{2x}{1+2x},\;\; \frac{3x}{1+3x}\;\;
 \dots,\;\; \frac{nx}{1+nx},\;\; \dots $$
which is a rational function in $\,n\,$ and this is **the**
characteristic property of a Hypergeometric series.

Assuming $\,x\ne 0\,$, let $\, y := 1/x.\,$ Then
$$ S(x) \!=\! 1 \!+\! \frac{1!}{(1\!+\!y)} \!+\!
 \frac{2!}{(1\!+\!y)(2\!+\!y)} \!+\! 
\frac{3!}{(1\!+\!y)(2\!+\!y)(3\!+\!y)} \!+\! \cdots. \tag{2} $$
This is a simple [Hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)
$$ S(x) = {}_2F_1(1,1;1+1/x;1) = 1/(1-x) \tag{3} $$
where the left side series has a complicated domain of
convergence and the right side has a simple pole
at $\,x=1.\,$

Your question was

> How does one obtain this series?

Quoting from the Wikipedia article:

> Many of the common mathematical functions can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function, or as limiting cases of it.

In this particular case, assume the Ansatz 
$$ f(x) \!:=\! a_0 \!+\! \frac{a_1\,x}{1\!+\!x} \!+\!
 \frac{a_2\,x^2}{(1\!+\!x)(1\!+\!2x)} \!+\!
 \frac{a_3\,x^3}{(1\!+\!x)(1\!+\!2x)(1\!+\!3x)}
 \!+\! \cdots. \tag{4} $$
Then by expanding into power series in $\,x\,$ we
have the result
$$ f(x) \!=\! a_0 \!+\! a_1\,x \!+\!
 (a_2\!-\!a_1)x^2 \!+\! (a_3\!-\!3a_2\!+\!a_1)x^3 \!+\!
 (a_4\!-\!6a_3\!+\!7a_2\!-\!a_1)x^4 \!+\! \cdots \tag{5} $$
which gets the power series coefficients of $\,f(x)\,$
from those of the series in equation $(4)$.

For this particular hypergeometric series, there is
another simple method to try. Define the partial sums
$$ S_n := \sum_{k=0}^n k!/(1+1/x)_k. \tag{6} $$
Then we can observe that 
$$ S_n = P_n x^n/(1+1/x)_n \tag{7} $$
where $\,P_n\,$ is a polynomial of degree $\,n\,$
with positive integer coefficients appearing in
[OEIS sequence A109822](https://oeis.org/A109822).
For example
$$ P_1\!=\! 1\!+\!2x, P_2\!=\! 1\!+\!4x\!+\!6x^2, P_3 = 1\!+\!7x\!+\!18x^2\!+\!24x^3. \tag{8} $$

But notice that the same coefficients appear in
[OEIS sequence A096747](https://oeis.org/A096747)
which has an extra $\,(n+1)!\,$ for each row. This
suggests looking at
 $$ 1/(1-x) - S_n = (n+1)!
\frac{x}{(1-x)(1+1/x)_{n+1}}. \tag{9} $$
This equality of two rational functions can be
proved by induction using telescoping sums.

Comment: You may have misread the series, unless you haven't.

Comment: @AndrewChin Oops! Fixed the denominators in (1).

Comment: @Somos May I ask how do you know it is a hypergeometric series in the first place? Is it a hunch or what?

Comment: @Somos How do you know the coefficients for $$ S(x) = {}_2F_1(\color{red}{1,1;1+1/x;1}) = 1/(1-x). \tag{3} $$

Is there a way to find the limiting function of this series?

Comment: @JamesWarthington If you are interested in that specific question, please submit it as another question because it has not a simple answer.

Comment: @Somos: If the LHS side of (3) has a complicated domain of convergence and the RHS is convergent for $|x|<1$, where is equality established?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I don't know yet.

Comment: @Somos I already post the question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497810/how-to-determine-the-coefficients-of-hypergeometric-functions

Comment: @JamesWarthington Thanks. I noticed.

Answer (score 8):

We can show the  identity
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n!x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\qquad\qquad0<x<1\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with the help of *[Gauss' summation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html)*.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n!x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\overline{n}}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1^{\overline{n}}1^{\overline{n}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\overline{n}}}\,\frac{1}{n!}\tag{3}\\
> &={}_2F_1\left(1,1;1+\frac{1}{x};1\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{\frac{1}{x}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}
> {\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}-1}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{1-x}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we expand with $\frac{1}{x^n}$ and use the *rising factorial* notation $q^{\overline{n}}=q(q+1)\cdots (q+n-1)$.
- In (3) we write $1^{\overline{n}}=n!$ and prepare the representation for use of *[hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series)*.
- In (4) we use the hypergeometric series notation
  \begin{align*}
  {}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{\overline{n}}b^{\overline{n}}}{c^{\overline{n}}}\,\frac{z^n}{n!}
  \end{align*}
  with $a=b=z=1$ and $c=1+\frac{1}{x}$.
- In (5) we use *[Gauss' summation formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html)*
  \begin{align*}
  {}_2F_1\left(a,b;c;1\right)=\frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}
  \end{align*}
  with $a=b=1$ and $c=1+\frac{1}{x}$ valid for $\Re\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)>1$.
- In (6) we use the identity $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,-1,-2,\ldots\}$.
- In (7) we finally cancel terms.

Comment: I sent you an important email concerning a live Zoom meeting on Egorychev method. Please check your email.

Answer (score 2):

**Proof of the Formula**

Below, we show inductively
$$
\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}+\frac{n!\,x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}\frac{1+nx}{1-x}\tag1
$$
where the empty sum is $0$ and the empty product is $1$.

[Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028) says that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{n!\,x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}
&=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\,\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+1+\frac1x\right)}\\
&\sim\frac{\Gamma\!\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{(n+1)^{1/x}}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $0\lt x\lt1$, the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}\tag3
$$
converges and the remainder term
$$
\frac{n!\,x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}\frac{1+nx}{1-x}\tag4
$$
vanishes as $n\to\infty$. Therefore, for $0\lt x\lt1$,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}=\frac1{1-x}}\tag5
$$

---

**Inductive Proof of $\bf{(1)}$**

Trivially, we have that $(1)$ is true for $n=0$.

Suppose that we have $(1)$ for some $n$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1-x}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}+\frac{n!\,x^n}{\prod_{j=0}^n(1+jx)}\frac{1+nx}{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}+\frac{n!\,x^n}{\prod_{j=0}^n(1+jx)}\left(\color{#C00}{1}+\color{#090}{\frac{(n+1)x}{1-x}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\color{#C00}{n}}\frac{k!\,x^k}{\prod_{j=1}^k(1+jx)}+\color{#090}{\frac{(n+1)!\,x^{n+1}}{\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}(1+jx)}\frac{1+(n+1)x}{1-x}}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $(1)$ holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Andrew Chin's comments, we face for the second series
$$S_\infty=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\, x^n}{\prod\limits_{m=0}^n(1+mx)}$$

Let $$a_n=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\, x^n}{\prod\limits_{m=0}^n(1+mx)}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)_n}$$ where appear Pochhammer symbols. So
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n=\frac{\frac{\Gamma (p+2)\, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}-1}{x-1}$$ and, assuming $0< x <1$
$$\lim_{p\to \infty } \, \frac{\Gamma (p+2) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}=0$$ since, using expansion for large $p$
$$\frac{\Gamma (p+2) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(p+1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) p^{1-\frac{1}{x}}\left(1+ \frac{(x-1) (2 x+1)}{2 x^2}\frac 1p+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)\right)$$