# Need some assistance on the expression $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, hypergeometric-function

[In this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3496698/how-to-derive-this-series/3496842#3496842), Markus Scheuer attempted to prove that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n!x^n}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{1}$$

He wrote as followed:

> $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n!\color{red}{x^n}}{\color{green}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{\left(\color{blue}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)^{\overline{n}}}\tag{2}$$$$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\color{purple}{1^{\overline{n}}1^{\overline{n}}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}\,\color{ForestGreen}{\frac{1}{n!}}\tag{3}$$

> where $q^{\overline{n}}=q(q+1)(q+2)...(q+n-1)$

I don't understand several points here:

1. First, on line $2$, why do $\color{red}{x^n}$ disspear? Did he multiply the denominator and numerator with $\dfrac{1}{x^n}$, if so, how can we multiply $\dfrac{1}{x^{n}}$ with the product $\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+jx)$?, if so, isn't the product is going to be $\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^n}+\dfrac{j}{x^{1-n}}\right)$? I suspect that he factored the $x$ from the denominator, but then why $x^n$ disappear?
2. Second, how do you covert the product $\prod_{j=1}^{n}(1+jx)$ into $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\overline{n}}$? I try to write down to get a feel of it:

$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\overline{n}}=(1+\dfrac{1}{x})(2+\dfrac{1}{x})(3+\dfrac{1}{x})...$

The look similar to the product, but after factoring out $x$

3. Why can $\color{purple}{1^{\overline{n}}1^{\overline{n}}}$ replace $n!$ ? Also, why there is a new $\color{forestgreen}{\dfrac{1}{n!}}$

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, he did do that but no, notice that you have $n$ copies of $x$ i.e., $x^n,$ if you put the $x^n$ inside the product like that, then you will have $x^{n^2}$ so $n^2$ copies. Instead, put one each per term in the product, so
   $$\prod  _{j=1}^n\left (\frac{1+jx}{x}\right )=\prod  _{j=1}^n\left (\frac{1}{x}+j\right )$$
2. 1. solves this mystery.
3. Cause $x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1),$so replacing $x=1,$ you get
   $$1\cdot (1+1)\cdot (1+2)\cdots (1+n-1)=1\cdot 2\cdots (n-1)\cdot n=n!,$$
   notice that there are two $1^{\overline{n}},$ so he multiplied and divide by $n!.$

Comment: @ I am confused with $x^{n^{2}}$. So let say the product is $(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)$. I need to pull out $x^3$, right? Then I will have $x^3(\frac{1}{x}+1)(\frac{1}{x}+2)(\frac{1}{x}+3)=x\cdot x\cdot x(\frac{1}{x}+1)(\frac{1}{x}+2)(\frac{1}{x}+3)$, each will be multiplied into the product, am I correct?

Comment: @JamesWarthington Exactly, the difference is that you wrote in the question that you were gonna get $x^3$ for the $3$ terms in the  product, so you were doing $x^3\cdot x^3\cdot x^3=x^9$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am all clear.

Comment: @JamesWarthington Cool! You are welcome.