# Divide a ball of volume $\frac{e^2}{6}n$ into $n$ slices of equal height. What is the product of the volumes of the slices as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: limits, volume, infinite-product

Divide a ball of volume $\frac{e^2}{6}n$ into $n$ slices of equal height, as shown below with example $n=8$. **What is the limit of the product of the volumes of the slices as $n\rightarrow\infty$?**

[image: Ball]

(If the image doesn't load for you, just imagine $n+1$ equally-spaced horizontal planes, and a ball that is tangent to the top and bottom planes. The planes, between the top and bottom planes, are where you cut the ball.)

I used volume of revolution, and after simplifying I got:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp{\left(2n-2n\ln{n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}}\ln{\left(k(n+1-k)-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)}\right)}$$

Wolfram does not evaluate this limit, but desmos tells me that when $n=10, 100, 1000, 10^6$, the product is approximately $1.847, 1.977, 1.997, 1.99999513$, respectively. So apparently the limit converges and equals $2$, but I do not know how to prove this.

(In case you're wondering how I got the number $\frac{e^2}{6}$: I used trial and error on desmos to hunt for the number that makes the limit converge, assuming such a number exists. I obtained a number like 1.231509. I entered this number into Wolfram and it suggested $\frac{e^2}{6}$.)

Comment: I think $e^2/6$ has to do with the product integral of the cross-sectional area function of the unit sphere, and the limit might be provable using a product-integral version of the Euler-Maclaurin formula (which can handle singular functions).

Comment: Here's a completely different way to cut a ball, that yields the same result. Imagine a sheaf of $n$ evenly spaced planes. A ball of volume $4n/\pi$ is tangent to the spine of the sheaf, and tangent to one of the planes. Now cut the ball along the planes. As $n\to\infty$, the product of the volumes converges to... you guessed it... $2$. (I used volume of rotation with polar coordinates, desmos and Wolfram.)

Comment: I have amended my answer so that it is 99% complete, have a look and feel free to suggest a lower bound on the product to complete the proof. Products are not my strong suit unfortunately :)

Comment: Just to clarify: is this a ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @robjohn Yes, it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Compute the Radius**

If the volume of the sphere is $\frac{e^2}6n$, then we must have
$$
r^3=\frac{ne^2}{8\pi}\tag1
$$

---

**Compute the Volumes of the Slices**

For $1\le k\le n$, we have the volume of slice $k$ to be
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{(2k-2-n)r/n}^{(2k-n)r/n}\pi(r^2-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{2\pi r^3}n-\frac\pi3\frac{r^3}{n^3}\left[(2k-n)^3-(2k-2-n)^3\right]\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{2\pi r^3}n-\frac{\pi r^3}{3n^3}\left[6(2k-n)^2-12(2k-n)+8\right]\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac{2\pi r^3}n-\frac{2\pi r^3}{3n^3}-\frac{2\pi r^3}{n^3}(2k-n-1)^2\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{8\pi r^3}{n^3}\left(\frac{n+1}2+\frac12\sqrt{n^2-\tfrac13}-k\right)\left(k-\frac{n+1}2+\frac12\sqrt{n^2-\tfrac13}\right)\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: integrate
$\text{(2b)}$: take the difference of the cubes
$\text{(2c)}$: complete the square
$\text{(2d)}$: factor the quadratic polynomial in $k$

---

**Compute the Product of the Volumes of the Slices**

Notice that the factor in the left parentheses in $\text{(2d)}$ is the same as the one in the right parentheses under the map $k\mapsto n+1-k$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
P_n
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\int_{(2k-2-n)r/n}^{(2k-n)r/n}\pi(r^2-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=\left(\frac{8\pi r^3}{n^3}\right)^n\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k-\frac{n+1}2+\frac12\sqrt{n^2-\tfrac13}\right)^2\tag{3a}\\
&=\left(\frac{8\pi r^3}{n^3}\right)^n\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2+\frac12\sqrt{n^2-\frac13}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{n-1}2+\frac12\sqrt{n^2-\frac13}\right)^2}\tag{3b}\\
&=\left(\frac{8\pi r^3}{n^3}\right)^n\frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac12-\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(\frac12-\frac1{12n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)^2}\tag{3c}\\[6pt]
&=\left(\frac{8\pi r^3}{n^3}\right)^n\frac{n!^2}{\pi n}n^{-\frac1{6n}+O\left(\frac1{n\log(n)}\right)}\tag{3d}\\[6pt]
&=\left(\frac{e^n}{n^n}\right)^2\frac{2\pi n\left(\frac{n^n}{e^n}\right)^2}{\pi n}n^{-\frac1{6n}+O\left(\frac1{n\log(n)}\right)}\tag{3e}\\[15pt]
&=2n^{-\frac1{6n}+O\left(\frac1{n\log(n)}\right)}\tag{3f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: use $\text{(2d)}$
$\text{(3b)}$: write the product as a ratio of Gamma functions
$\text{(3c)}$: $\sqrt{n^2-\frac13}=n-\frac1{6n}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$
$\text{(3d)}$: [Gautschi's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028) yields $\Gamma(x+s)=\Gamma(x)x^se^{O(1/x)}$ for $0\le s\le1$
$\text{(3e)}$: Stirling's approximation
$\text{(3f)}$: simplify

$\text{(3f)}$ says that the limit of the product is indeed $2$.

---

**Further Results**

If we use the more precise asymptotic approximations
$$
\Gamma(x+s)\sim\Gamma(x)x^se^{-\frac{s(1-s)}{2x}}\tag4
$$
and
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}e^{\frac1{12n}}\tag5
$$
we get that the coefficient of the $O\!\left(\frac1{n\log(n)}\right)$ term in $\text{(3f)}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
C
&=\frac16\frac{\Gamma'(1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}-\frac1{12}\tag{6a}\\[6pt]
&=-0.41058500433690391324\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$
According to the table
$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
n&n^2\log(P_n/2)+\frac16n\log(n)-Cn\\\hline
1&-0.074321645451096396990\\
10&-0.040105155755794398809\\
100&-0.035166254783256555024\\
1000&-0.034391063053238965551\\
1000000&-0.034269677264259024828\\
10000000&-0.034269484677864450270
\end{array}
$$
if we let $D=-0.034269$, we apparently get
$$
P_n\sim2n^{-\frac1{6n}}e^{\frac{Cn+D}{n^2}}\tag7
$$

Comment: Thanks. I would love to accept this answer, but limitations in my current knowledge prevent me from fully understanding it (especially 3d), and I cannot in good conscience accept an answer that I do not fully understand. (I'm not asking for more explanation; I think the rest is up to me.) Anyway, I benefit a lot from this answer: it greatly strengthens my suspicion that there is no easy way to evaluate the limit. So, +1.

Comment: Combining this answer with Ninan Munshi's answer would constitute a curious way to prove that $ \lim_{m\to\infty}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{3}}{m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{4}}=1$.

Comment: Gautschi's Inequality is explained in the link provided. It simply relies on the log-convexity of the Gamma function, which is proven in the answer linked there. It is quite useful when dealing with the Gamma function at large, non-integer arguments.

Comment: That product is asymptotically $\left(\frac{57m}4\right)^{-\frac1{24m}}$, which tends to $1$ as $m\to\infty$. Actually, $\frac{57}4$ should be $2e^{-\Gamma'(1/2)/\Gamma(1/2)}=14.24857934$, but the difference becomes insignificant as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: I now understand how to go from your line 3a to 3d, but in a (perhaps) different way. I used equation 5.8.1 from [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.8). Answer accepted.

Answer (score 5):

For simplicity's sake, let's assume $n=2m$ is even and let's assume we don't know the volume constant $V$ and say we have a sphere of radius $R_m = C\cdot m^{1/3}$. With this we can say that the volume of the $k$th slice from the "equator" would be (using the solid of revolution/cylindrical coordinates)

$$v_k = 2\pi \int_{\frac{(k-1)R_m}{m}}^{\frac{kR_m}{m}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R_m^2-z^2}}r\:dr\:dz = \pi\int_{\frac{(k-1)R_m}{m}}^{\frac{kR_m}{m}}R_m^2-z^2\:dz$$
$$ = \pi C^3\left[1-\frac{k^2}{m^2}+\frac{k}{m^2}-\frac{1}{3m^2}\right]$$

Now stating our problem in its final form, does the sqaure root of our desired product exist in the limit

$$\sqrt{P} = \lim_{m\to\infty}(\pi C^3)^m\prod_{k=1}^m \left[1-\frac{k^2}{m^2}+\frac{k}{m^2}-\frac{1}{3m^2}\right]$$

Taking the log of the product retrieves the following the sum

$$\lim_{m\to\infty} m \left(\log (\pi C^3) + \sum_{k=1}^m \log\left[1-\frac{k^2}{m^2}+\frac{k}{m^2}-\frac{1}{3m^2}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{m}\right)$$

The term on the right is almost a Riemann sum (courtesy of squeeze theorem), but it diverges at a rate $\theta(m)$. Fortunately for us, the term on the left diverges at exactly the same rate. The Riemann sum evaluates to

$$\int_0^1 \log(1-x^2)\:dx = \log 4 - 2$$

Immediately we get that for the product to converge at all, the constant from the beginning must have been

$$\begin{cases}\log(\pi C^3) = 2 - \log 4 \\ \frac{4\pi}{3}C^3m = V\cdot(2m)\end{cases} \implies V = \frac{e^2}{6}$$

Working back with the product, we arrive at

$$\sqrt{P} = \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{e}{2m}\right)^{2m}\prod_{k=1}^m m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{3}$$

From Stirling's approximation we have

$$\left(\frac{2m}{e}\right)^{2m} \sim \frac{1}{2^{2m}\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{(4m)!}{2^{2m}(2m)!}$$

where we recognize the term on the right as the product of the odd integers between $1$ and $4m$. Since we can multiply the integers in whichever order we want, we should be clever about the order and not blindly multiply them in an ascending fashion. This lets us rewrite the limit as

$$\sqrt{P}=\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{e}{2m}\right)^{2m}}{2^{2m}\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{2^{2m}(2m)!}{(4m)!}}\right)\cdot\left( \lim_{m\to\infty}2^{2m}\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{2^{2m}(2m)!}{(4m)!}\prod_{k=1}^m m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$

$$=(1)\cdot\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt{2}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{4m^2-4k^2+4k-\frac{4}{3}}{(2m-2k+1)(2m+2k-1)}\right)$$
$$ = \lim_{m\to\infty}\sqrt{2}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^m \frac{m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{3}}{m^2-k^2+k-\frac{1}{4}}$$

The product is bounded above by $1$ and numerical investigations show that the product tends towards $1$, but I have not yet found a proper lower bound for squeeze theorem. In the end though, squeeze theorem will show that the limit of the product of the slices will be

$$P = (\sqrt{P})^2 = 2$$

Comment: I'm trying to show that the last product converges to $1$. I expressed it as a sum of logs, then tried the integral test. I used technology to get the indefinite integral (which is complicated), but then it's hard to prove that the definite integral converges.