# What periodic function does $\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2}$ tend to?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, periodic-functions

If one graphs $$ y= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2} = \frac{x!}{2^x  \left( \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)!\right)^2} $$

One immediately notices that as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ the function tends to some periodic function that looks an awful lot like $\tan(x)$. Is there a way to make this idea precise and state what that function is? I was thinking something like, there exists a periodic function $f(x)$ such that $f(x) - y(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

See this image:

Which was produced using desmos.com/calculator

[image]

Comment: I fixed what appears to have been a typo. If I was mistaken, just roll it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Asymptotic Behavior**

[Euler's Reflection Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) says
$$
\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\pi\csc(\pi x)\tag1
$$
and the [Legendre Duplication Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) says
$$
\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma\!\left(x+\tfrac12\right)=\frac{2\sqrt\pi}{4^x}\Gamma(2x)\tag2
$$
[Gautschi's Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103028) says that for $0\lt s\lt1$,
$$
x^{1-s}<\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x+s)}<(x+1)^{1-s}\tag3
$$
which can be extended to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(x+s)}{\Gamma(x)\,x^s}=1\tag4
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x\Gamma\left(\frac x2+1\right)^2}
&=\frac1{2^x}\frac{\pi\csc(-\pi x)}{\Gamma(-x)}\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{x}2\right)^2}{\pi^2\csc^2\left(-\frac{\pi x}2\right)}\tag{5a}\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\frac1{2^x}\tan\left(-\frac{\pi x}2\right)\frac{\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(-x)}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2+\frac12\right)}\tag{5b}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt\pi}\tan\left(-\frac{\pi x}2\right)\frac{\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(-\frac{x}2+\frac12\right)}\tag{5c}\\[3pt]
&\sim\frac{\tan(-\pi x/2)}{\sqrt{-\pi x/2}}\tag{5d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5a):}$ $(1)$ says $\Gamma(x+1)=\frac{\pi\csc(-\pi x)}{\Gamma(-x)}$
$\text{(5b):}$ $\frac{\csc(-\pi x)}{\csc^2\left(-\frac{\pi x}2\right)}=-\frac12\tan\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)$
$\text{(5c):}$ $(2)$ says $\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{x}2\right)\Gamma\left(-\frac{x}2+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(-x)}=\frac{2\sqrt\pi}{2^{-x}}$
$\text{(5d):}$ $(4)$ says $\frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{x}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{x}2+\frac12\right)}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{-x/2}}$

---

**Not Really Like Tangent**

$\dfrac{\tan(-\pi x/2)}{\sqrt{-\pi x/2}}$ is not periodic, though it appears to be over short spans. As $x\to-\infty$, the tangent-like shapes get flattened out.

Here is how they look near $x=-15$:

[image]

and here is how they look near $x=-1005$:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function%E2%80%93Legendre_formula) can be written as
$$
\frac{\Gamma(2z)}{2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z+\tfrac12)} = \frac{\Gamma(z)}{\sqrt\pi}.
$$
Applying this with $z=\frac x2+\frac12$ gives
$\displaystyle
\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x\Gamma(\tfrac x2+1)} = \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac x2+\tfrac12)}{\sqrt\pi}
$,
and so
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2} = \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac x2+\tfrac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)}.
$$
Applying the [reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) $\Gamma(z) = \dfrac\pi{\Gamma(1-z)\sin\pi z}$ twice yields
$$
\frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac{\Gamma(\tfrac x2+\tfrac12)}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)} = \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac{\Gamma(-\frac x2)\sin\pi(\frac x2+1)}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac x2)\sin\pi(\frac x2+\frac12)} = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac{\Gamma(-\frac x2)}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac x2)} \tan\tfrac{\pi x}2.
$$
Finally, [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling%27s_formula) implies that $\Gamma(y+\frac12)\sim \Gamma(y)\sqrt y$ as $y\to\infty$ (where $\sim$ means that the quotient of the two sides tends to $1$). Therefore
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2} = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi} \frac{\Gamma(-\frac x2)}{\Gamma(\frac12-\frac x2)} \tan\tfrac{\pi x}2 \sim -\sqrt{\frac2{\pi|x|}}\tan\tfrac{\pi x}2
$$
as $x\to-\infty$. So there is a tangent function involved, but also a slight decay.

Comment: (+1) I didn't see your answer until after Claude's after I posted. I have added some images to show how the decay affects the shapes.

Answer (score 4):

For negative values of $x$,  $$y= \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x\, \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2} $$ is closer and closer to
$$\sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) \csc (\pi  (x+1))=-\frac{1}{2} \tan \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)$$ This comes from Euler's reflection formula of the gamma function.

**Edit**

As @GregMartin commented, I forgot the next term of the expansion. So, give all credit to him.

Using more terms, for negative values of $x$
$$y=- \sqrt{-\frac{2}{\pi x}} \tan \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\Bigg[ 1-\frac{1}{4 x}+\frac{1}{32 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\Bigg]$$

It could even be better if the series expansion is made a simple Padé approximant such as
$$\frac {64 x^2-8 x+11 }{64 x^2+8 x+11 }+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$

In order to check how good (or bad) is the approximation, I computed
$$I_n=\int_{-2n-0.99}^{-2n+0.99} \Bigg[\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x\, \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2}+ \sqrt{-\frac{2}{\pi x}}\, \tan \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)\,\,\frac {64 x^2-8 x+11 }{64 x^2+8 x+11 }\Bigg]^2\, dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & I_n \\
 10 & 5.371 \times 10^{-16} \\
 9  & 1.766\times 10^{-15} \\
 8  & 6.733\times 10^{-15} \\
 7  & 3.105\times 10^{-14} \\
 6  & 1.846\times 10^{-13}  \\
 5  & 1.567\times 10^{-12} \\
 4  & 2.271\times 10^{-11} \\
 3  & 7.961\times 10^{-10} \\
 2  & 1.562\times 10^{-07} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

What could be interesting is to see if we can approximate the roots of
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{2^x\, \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)^2}=k $$

Comment: As we see from my answer (and graphical confirmation), this is off by a factor of $\sqrt{\frac8{\pi|x|}}$.

Comment: @GregMartin. You are right ! I forgot the next term. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @GregMartin. The problem is that I do not see th graph; then too often missing terms. This plus age = complex life. Cheers :-)

Comment: (+1) I had this page up all evening and didn't see your answer until I posted. Mine has some added details, though not as many terms of the asymptotic expansion.

Comment: @robjohn. Thanks. Have a look at the $I_n$.