# Proof: $X\ge 0, r>0\Rightarrow E(X^r)=r\int_0^{\infty}x^{r-1}P(X>x)dx$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

As the title states, the problem at hand is proving the following:

$X\ge 0, r>0\Rightarrow E(X^r)=r\int_0^{\infty}x^{r-1}P(X>x)dx$

---

**Attempt/thoughts on a solution**

I am guessing this is an application of Fubini's Theorem, but wouldn't that require writing $P(X>x)$ as an expectation? If so, how is this accomplished?

Thoughts and help are appreciated.

Comment: It is $\int_0^\infty \Pr(X^r \gt x)\,dx$, which is $\int_0^\infty \Pr(X \gt x^{1/r})\,dx$. Make the change of variable $u^r=x$.

Comment: @Justin: I'm quite curious about the reference of this exercise. Could you tell me in which book you encountered it?

Comment: Even though this post is slightly different, I’d like to link it to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841). Also see the meta post for [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof: Consider the expectation of the identity
$$
X^r=r\int_0^{X}x^{r-1}\,\mathrm dx=r\int_0^{+\infty}x^{r-1}\mathbf 1_{X>x}\,\mathrm dx.
$$