# Meaning of almost surely nonnegative.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

I'm confused with the terminology 'almost surely'(a.s.) in probability theory. If $X$ is a random variable, does the following statement equivalent?

1. $X$ is almost surely nonegative.
2. $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$
3. $\mathbb{P}(X \geq 0)=1$ a.s.

If we are given the first and second statement, how to prove $\mathbb{E}(X)>0$?

Comment: An event happens almost surely if it happens with probability $1$. So $X\geq 0$ almost surely means $\mathbb{P}(X\geq 0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An event is said to happen almost surely if the probability of that event is $1$.

$X$ is almost surely non-negative means that $P(X\ge0)=1$.

The third statement makes no sense.

The second statement $P(X>0)>0$ does not imply $\Bbb E(X)>0$. For example, take $X$ to be the random variable where $P(X=-1)=\frac23, P(X=1)=\frac13$.

When both first and second statement holds, check [Expectation of nonnegative RV](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502651/expectation-of-nonnegative-rv) and [A nonnegative random variable has zero expectation if and only if it is zero almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897876/a-nonnegative-random-variable-has-zero-expectation-if-and-only-if-it-is-zero-alm/897893)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If we are given the first and second statement, how to prove $EX>0$? Sorry for that mistake, I have edited it.

Comment: @Cloud Note that if $\mathbb{P}(X>0)>0$ then there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X>\frac{1}{n})>0$. Now use Markov's inequality.

Comment: Note that Markov's inequality holds for non-negative random variables only.

Comment: @QED Yes, but we assume $X$ is almost surely nonnegative.

Comment: @Mark The question was so basic, it is more elementary than the proof of Markov;s inequality, right? And my above comment was for the OP, stressing on the fact that why non-negativity of the r.v. is necessary.