# show $\mathbb{E} \vert X \vert = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\{\vert X \vert>y\})dy \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P \{\vert X \vert>y\} $.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Looking for a hint to show $\mathbb{E} \vert X \vert = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(\{\vert X \vert>y\})dy \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb P \{\vert X \vert>y\} $.

This is from Theorem 2.3.7 in Durrett (Probability: Theory and examples)

The first equality makes sense by Fubini and the definition of expectation (Durrett Lemma 2.2.8). I'm having a hard time showing the second, though. My gut intuition makes me feel like it should be the other direction.

Comment: Isn't there a symbol missing in the RHS? $\{\lvert X\rvert > y\}$ is a set, assuming usual notations; and there is no $n$ in the summand, only an unbound "$y$."

Comment: Sum should start from 0, otherwise take any $X$, s.t. $|X|\leq$ and $RHS=0$.

Comment: Even though this post is slightly different, I’d like to link it to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841). Also see the meta post for [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647).

Comment: A proof using Fubini (and integrating $dP$): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536442/intuitive-explanation-for-mathbbex-int-0-infty-1-fx-dx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mention, the first equation is essentially Fubini, along with rewriting $\mathbb{P}\{\lvert X\rvert > y\}$ as an integral.

For the inequality on the right: observe that
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > y\} dy 
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > y\} dy \leq 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > n\} dy \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > n\}
\end{align}$$
using the fact that for $y \geq x$, $\mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > y\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X\rvert > x\}$ since $\{ \lvert X\rvert > y\} \subseteq \{ \lvert X\rvert > x\}$.

Comment: Very cute proof!