# Conditional expectation of second order statistic

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $X_1, X_2$ be two independent, non-negative random variables with finite means from the same distribution function $F(x)$ and density function $f(x)$.
Denote their order statistics with $0 < Y_1 < Y_2$.

I want to compute $E(Y_2 | Y_1 = y_1)$ or to be more specific I want to show for $y_1 > 0$:
\begin{align*}
E(Y_2 | Y_1 = y_1) = y_1 + \frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} 1 - F(u) du}{1 - F(y_1)}.
\end{align*}
The joint density function of $Y_1,Y_2$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{Y_1, Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = 2 f(y_1) f(y_2) \chi_{y_1 < y_2},
\end{align*}
where $\chi$ is the indicator function.
The conditional expectation above can be computed by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\int_0^{\infty} y_2 f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) dy_2} {\int_0^{\infty} f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)  dy_2}
= \frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} y_2 f(y_1) f(y_2)  dy_2} {\int_{y_1}^{\infty} f(y_1) f(y_2) dy_2}
= \frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} y_2 f(y_2)  dy_2} {\int_{y_1}^{\infty} f(y_2) dy_2} 
= \frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} y_2 f(y_2)  dy_2} {1 - F(y_1)} 
\end{align*}
At this point I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{y_1}(1-F(u))du&=\left(u(1-F(u)\right)\left|_{0}^{y_1}\right.+\int_0^{y_1}uf(u)du\\
&=y_1(1-F(y_1))+\int_0^{y_1}uf(u)du
\end{align}
[further](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690740/prove-that-ex-int-0-infty-pxx-dx-int-0-infty-1-f-xx/1691534#1691534) $\int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F(u))du=\int_0^{\infty}uf(u)du$ hence
\begin{align}
\int_{y_1}^{\infty} (1-F(u))du&=\int_0^{\infty}uf(u)du-\int_0^{y_1}uf(u)du\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}uf(u)du-y_1(1-F(y_1))-\int_0^{y_1}uf(u)du\\
&=\int_{y_1}^{\infty}uf(u)du-y_1(1-F(y_1))
\end{align}

implying that $$\frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} u f(u)  du} {1 - F(y_1)} =\frac{\int_{y_1}^{\infty} (1-F(u))du+y_1(1-F(y_1))} {1 - F(y_1)}$$

as you are after.