# Another formula for Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I came across the following question:

> If $ X $ is a continuous random variable $ (-\infty<X<\infty) $ having distribution function $ F(x) $, show that $$ E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}[1-F(x)-F(-x)]\,\mathrm{d}x, $$ provided $ x[1-F(x)-F(-x)]\to0 $ as $ x\to\infty $.

I went through a similar problem [posted here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1690740/621407), but cannot seem to generalise the result as required. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Write $X = X^+ - X^-$ where $X^+ = \max(X, 0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X, 0)$ and apply the linked answer.

Comment: $P(X^+ > x) = P(X > x)$ and $P(X^- > x) = P(X < -x)$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Still can't get it. I am getting $ F^{+}(t)=F(t)-F(0) $ and $ F^{-}(t)=F(0)-F(-t) $. And how do I use the added condition?

Comment: I don't think the other condition is really needed but I guess if you assume that $X$ has a density then you can write $1-F(x)-F(-x) = x'[1 - F(x) - F(-x)]$ and do integration by parts on the RHS.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thank you. Why don't you post this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: I posted a summary of my comments as an asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to write $X = X^+ - X^-$ where $X^+ = \max(X, 0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X, 0)$. Now notice that for $x > 0$ we have $P(X^+ > x) = P(X > x)$ and $P(X^- > x) = P(X < -x)$. Now apply the formula of the linked answer separately for $X^+$ and $X^-$ to get the required expression. Notice that the condition $x[1-F(x)-F(-x)] \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ was not needed.

Alternatively, if you assume $X$ has a density, you can write
$$\int_0^\infty (1-F(x)-F(-x))\,dx = \int_0^\infty x'(1-F(x)-F(-x))\,dx$$
and integrate by parts to get $E(X)$ but then you would need to use the additional condition.