# Measure theoretic Fubini/Tonelli theorems: integrating w.r.t variables $t,x,y$ instead of measures $\mu, \nu, P$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I've been introduced to the Fubini-Tonelli theorems in my probability/measure theory class in the following way:
[image: Fubini-Tonelli Theorems]

or if you want a similar looking pdf: [https://www.cmi.ac.in/~prateek/measure_theory/2010-10-06.pdf](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Eprateek/measure_theory/2010-10-06.pdf). Notice that all the integrals in the image and the pdf are w.r.t. measures like $\mu, \nu$ and NOT variables like $t,x,y$.

**Question setup:** Now, looking at the answer to the following question: [Intuitive explanation for $\mathbb{E}X= \int_0^\infty 1-F(x) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536442/intuitive-explanation-for-mathbbex-int-0-infty-1-fx-dx), one of the integrals is $dP$ (a probability measure) and one is $dt$, which is not a measure. This makes me uncomfortable because then it doesn't "look like" we can use the above versions of Fubini/Tonelli on it, because the connotation of $dt$ is *Riemann* integration and not *Lebesgue* integration.

> **Question:** can we change the $dt$ integral to be something like $d\lambda$ (where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure)? When are we sure we can interchange between $dt$ (or $dx$ or $dy$) integrals with integrals w.r.t measures like $\lambda$, especially in these infinite cases?
>
> The reason I specify the infinite case (and the one in the linked question in particular, which is special because the inside function, $f(x) = P(X<x)$, is a monotonically decreasing bounded function) is because I know for the bounded, interval case, we have: [General condition that Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are the same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829927/general-condition-that-riemann-and-lebesgue-integrals-are-the-same).
>
> Basically, can someone tell me how to get the $dt,dx,dy$ integrals into the measure theoretic form, and the criterion for knowing when I can do this interchange or not?

I get that this may be a simple misunderstanding of notation on my part, so if that's the case I hope someone can explain the correct way of interpreting this notation.

Comment: The $dt$ in your Question setup paragraph is nothing but integration w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. The proof of the formula $EX =\int_0^{\infty} P(X>t) dt$ is completely in the framework of Fubini/Tonelli Theorem

Comment: @KaboMurphy It looks a lot like normal Riemann integration to me... I guess I just don't understand how to interpret the symbols $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$. It doesn't look like it's involving a measure at all, so if it actually is, I want to know how we can say that it is. Why is it justified we can just encode BOTH Riemann and Lebesgue integration into one "$dt$"? And I know in general the Riemann and Lebesgue integrals are different, so I want to be careful.

Comment: Doesn't the proof you linked still go through with the Lebesgue measure producted with the probability measure?

Comment: generally, working with measures, we omit the writing of specific variables, that is, it is generally written as $\,\mathrm d \mu $ instead of $\,\mathrm d \mu (x)$ or $\,\mathrm d x$, however all these expressions have the same meaning in context. By the other hand the expression $\int_0^\infty f(x) d x$ is an improper integral of Riemann, however if $f$ is absolutely integrable (that is, if $\int_0^\infty |f(x)| dx$ exists as a finite value) then $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx=\int_{(0,\infty)}f d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure

Comment: That's a very involved way of introducing the theorem of Fubini-Tonelli. Actually, that theorem is very natural; just like you can swap two finite sums, such as $$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_{ij}= \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}, $$ simply because the sum is commutative, you can swap two integrals, under minimal assumptions. That's all. Measurability, sigma-algebras, etc... all of that is technical blah-blah which comes much later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that you need to know are these theorems, that I will state here without proof:

> **Theorem 1:** every Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue integrable, that is, if $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x$ exists for some pair $-\infty <a<b<\infty $, then $\int_a^b f(x) \,\mathrm d x=\int_{[a,b]}f\,\mathrm d \lambda $ where the latter is an integral of Lebesgue respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda $.
>
> **Theorem 2:** if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable (w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure in the real line) and the set of discontinuities of $f$ have measure zero then $f$ is improperly Riemann integrable and $\int_{\Bbb R }f\,\mathrm d \lambda =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm d x$.
>
> **Theorem 3:** let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ Riemann integrable in any bounded interval. Then if $f$ is non-negative or the improper integral of Riemann $\int_a^b|f| \,\mathrm d x$ is finite (for $-\infty\leqslant a\leqslant b\leqslant \infty$) then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_{(a,b)}f\,\mathrm d \lambda $, where the first is an improper integral of Riemann, and the latter is an integral of Lebesgue w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

Almost any other case of functions $f:I\to \Bbb R $, for some interval $I\subset \Bbb R $, can be reduced to one of the theorems above considering the trivial extension $\tilde f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
\tilde f(x):=\begin{cases}
f(x),&x\in I\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Hope it helps.

Comment: Is the following case included in Theorem 3: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx = \infty \iff \int_{\mathbb R} |f| d\lambda = \infty$?

Comment: @D.R. yes, because the function $|f|$ is non-negative. I edited a bit the last theorem to make it more general or easier to apply

Comment: Thank you. Where might I find proofs of these 3 theorems?

Comment: @D.R. I studied it in the textbook _Analysis III_ of Amann and Escher, however this textbook is not easy to get into. The definition of the integrals and the monotone convergence theorem make easy to prove theorem 1 and 3. The theorem 2 is more involved and you can see a proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_Theorem). However I extended theorem 2 to the case of improper integrals of Riemann assuming that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, what is also easy to prove using the definition of improper integral of Riemann