# Expectation of min(X,1)

Tags: probability

On several occasions, I've come across the following statement:

Let $X$ be a random variable. Then we have, for $X$ nonnegative,

$E[\min(X,1)] = \int_0^1 Pr(X\geq u) du$.

How would one go about to show this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that
$$
\operatorname EY=\int_0^\infty\Pr\{Y\ge y\}\mathrm dy
$$
for any non-negative random variable $Y$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578358/show-that-ex-int-0-inftypx-ge-xdx-for-non-negative-random-variable)). In this case $Y=\min\{X,1\}$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E\min\{X,1\}
&=\int_0^\infty\Pr\{\min\{X,1\}\ge x\}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\Pr\{\min\{X,1\}\ge x\}\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty\Pr\{\min\{X,1\}\ge x\}\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_0^1\Pr\{X\ge x\}\mathrm dx
\end{align*}
since $\Pr\{\min\{X,1\}\ge x\}=\Pr\{X\ge x\}$ when $0\le x\le1$ and $\Pr\{\min\{X,1\}\ge x\}=0$ when $x>1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Show the pointwise equality
$$
\min(X,1)=\int_0^1\mathbf{1}_{u\leqslant X}\,\mathrm du
$$
and take expectations on both sides.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align*}
\\ \operatorname E\min\{X,1\} = \operatorname E({\operatorname E[\min\{X,1\} |X]}) &= {\operatorname E[\min\{X,1\} |X\le1]}\cdot Pr\{X\le1\} + {E[\min\{X,1\} |X\ge1]}\cdot Pr\{X\ge1\} = \\
&= \int_0^1\Pr\{X\ge x\}\mathrm dx\cdot Pr\{X\le1\}+1\cdot Pr\{X\ge1\}\\
\end{align*}
Law of total expectation has been used here, I wonder where's the mistake.