# Probability of a random variable being bigger than a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I came across a problem where X is a **non-negative RV with CDF $F_X(x)$**, and I have to show that $$E[min(X,1)] = P(X\geq U),$$ being U a **uniformly distributed variable from 0 to 1**, independent of X. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637171/expectation-of-minx-1) they show that $$E[min(X,1)] = \int_0^1 P(X\geq x)dx,$$ but I didn't grasp how this probability can "get out" of the integral for a uniformly distributed U.

Comment: Try writing out the integral explicitly. First we can assume that $X \in [0,1]$. Then, $P(X \geq U)$ is an integral over a subset of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and the pdf is just $p(x)$. (Nitpick: You forgot to mention that $U$ is independent from $X$.)

Comment: $P(X \ge U) = \int_0^1 \int_u^\infty f_X(x) \ dx du = \int_0^1 [1 - F_X(u)] \ du = \int_0^1 P(X \ge u) \ du$. As Lorenzo points out, this requires $X,U$ to be independent.

Comment: Oops, indeed it is stated in the problem that they are i.i.d. Edited the question to add this information.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that the uniform variable is between $k/n$ and $(k+1)/n,$ then the probability that your variable is bigger approximately equals $P(X\geq (k+1)/n).$ Now, the probability that $X>U$ is the sum of the disjoint events $U_k,$ so the Riemann sum converges exactly to the integral on your RHS.