# $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X>y)dy$ for non-negative r.v. $X$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

First off, I am aware of this answer: [Show that $E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X\ge x)dx$ for non-negative random variable $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578358/show-that-ex-int-0-inftypx-ge-xdx-for-non-negative-random-variable), but I want to know what is missing in my approach.
I would calculate as follows $$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xP(dx)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x}dyP(dx)$$

where I use Fubini with $$0<y<x \text{ and}-\infty<x<\infty$$ giving $$0<y<\infty\text{ and } y<x<\infty$$ 
hence the above expression becomes $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_y^{\infty}P(dx)dy=\int_0^{\infty}P(X>y)dy$$

Now this is the right solution but nowhere did I (explicitly) use that $X$ is non-negative.
Could someone point out what I am missing.

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_0^xdy$ if $x<0$??? It arises in the RHS of your expression for $\mathbb EX$.

Comment: @drhab Still $x$ I suppose. E.g. for $x=-2$: $\int_0^{-2}dy = -\int_{-2}^0dy=-[y]^0_{-2}=-(0+2)=-2$.

Comment: In the second line you are saying to use Fubini with $0<y<x$, but no such $y$ exists if $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't assume $E|X|<\infty$ you need non-negativity to switch the order of integration. The version of Fubini for non-negative r.v. is sometimes called Tonelli's theorem.

Check out wikipedia's entry on [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions) and its counterexamples.