# Why does $\int_0^{\infty} \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c} \, dc = \int_0^X dc$ hold?

Tags: random-variables

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Why does the following hold:

$$\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c} \, dc = \int_0^X dc = X \quad\text{(?)} $$

I am confused because I thought that $\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c} \, dc$ gives me something like $\sum_{c \in [0,\infty)}\lambda(\{X > c\})$.

EDIT: This was the original equation: $\mathbb E(\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c}) \, dc =\mathbb E(\int_0^X dc) = \mathbb E(X)$. Maybe I read this wrong!

Comment: The integral in question has nothing to do with randomness of $X$.

Comment: This is part of $\int\limits_0^{\infty} (1-F_X(c) dc = \mathbb E(X)$

Comment: Let me elaborate my comment: the integral in question is a direct consequence of the following *deterministic* result: for any $a \geq 0$, $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{ c < a \}} \, dc = \int_{0}^{a} dc = a. $$ Since this is true for any $a \geq 0$, you can even plug $a = X(\omega)$ which depends on some variable $\omega$ that is completely irrelevant to the computation of the integral above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are kinda right, I had: $\mathbb E(\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c}) \, dc =\mathbb E(\int_0^X dc) = \mathbb E(X)$

Comment: @Pazu : My earlier comment was mistaken. I made the crude mistake of neglecting the fact that $c$ is a bound variable. The answer by user365239 is correct.

Comment: This was posted countlessly many times on the site (by several users, including me). Is your question about a specific post on the site?

Comment: @Did : I think the thing that's been posted repeatedly involved the proposition that $$ \int_0^\infty \Pr(X>c)\,dc = \operatorname{E}(X) \text{ if  }\Pr(X>0) = 1.$$ But this is simpler than that.; it just says $$ \int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X\,>\,c}(c) \,dc = X. $$ See the answer by user365239. Nothing in that answer, nor in the question, depends on $X$ being a random variable; that comes in afterward.

Comment: @Pazu : I now suspect that you read that $$ \int_0^\infty \Pr(X>c)\,dc = \operatorname{E}(X) \text{ if  }\Pr(X>0) = 1 $$ and then in a proposed proof of that you found $$ \int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X\,>\,c}(c) \,dc = \int_0^X \, dc = X. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, I am referring to the identity between random variables.

Comment: @Did : ok, But the fact that it is a random variable doesn't really have anything to do with the proof of that identity. $\qquad$

Comment: @Did I understand if you want to close the thread. I think I got everything together and the proof was indeed discussed several times on this site.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It has not, but there are definitely two identities here, one being the integrated form of the other, and I am referring to the other (if the mention "random variable" irks you, replace it by "function").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(X&gt;y)dy$ for non-negative r.v. $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140922/ex-int-0-inftypxydy-for-non-negative-r-v-x)

Comment: One thing is missing here: If $\Pr(X>0)= 1$ then $$ \begin{align} X & = \int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X\,>\,c}(c) \, dc \\  \\ \text{and therefore } \operatorname{E}(X) & = \operatorname{E}\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X\,>\,c} (c) \,dc \\  \\ & = \int_0^\infty \operatorname{E}(\boldsymbol{1}_{X\,>\,c} (c)) \, dc \longleftarrow \text{How is this step justified?} \\  \\ & = \int_0^\infty \Pr(X>c)\,dc. \end{align} $$ To justify the step mentioned above, I would cite Tonelli's theorem,$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$which says that if a function being integrated is non-negative, then the double integral equals the iterated integral in either of the two orders regardless of whether that is finite or $+\infty. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry but the notation $$\mathbf 1_{X>c}(c)$$ is absurd. One can either write $$X=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{X>c}\,dc$$ or $$X(\omega)=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{X>c}(\omega)\,dc$$ or even $$X(\omega)=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{X(\omega)>c}\,dc$$

Comment: Even if this poster initially intended this to be a question with content other than what it's turned out to be, and that other content turned out to duplicate another question (and it does) nonetheless what was intended is not what happened, and this is not an exact duplicate, and it actually gives a slightly interesting way of looking at the matter that is not necessarily present in that older question.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_{X>c} \; dc = \int_0^X 1 \; dc + \int_X^\infty 0 \; dc  = \int_0^X 1 \; dc = X
$$

Comment: Thanks you are of course totally right. I think I missed that $\int_0^\infty \boldsymbol{1}_{X > c} dc$ defines a random variable itself.