# Expected value of a non-negative random variable

Tags: probability

How do I prove that $\int_0^\infty Pr(Y\geq y) dy = E[Y]$ if $Y$ is a non-negative random variable?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando

Answer (score 20):

Assuming we have a continuous random variable with an existant probability density function $f_Y$.

$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \Pr(Y \geqslant y) \operatorname d y
& =
\int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f_Y(z)\operatorname d z\operatorname d y 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty \int_0^z f_Y(z)\operatorname d y\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty f_Y(z)\int_0^z 1\operatorname d y\;\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\int_0^\infty z f_Y(z)\operatorname d z 
\\[1ex] & =
\mathsf E[Y] 
\end{align}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you changed the order of integration to arrive at the limits of 0 and z in the inner integral?

Comment: $\begin{align} & \text{The double integral is performed over the interval:} \\ & \{(y,z):z\in[0,\infty)\cap y\in[z,\infty)\} \\ \equiv & \{(y,z):0\leqslant z\leqslant y<\infty\} \\ \equiv & \{(y,z):y\in [0,\infty)\cap z\in[0,y]\} \end{align}$ @user2510050

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Thanks, I added your proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/mean-nnrvar).

Comment: the OP did not make assumption of continuity

Answer (score 14):

This proof assumes a background in measure theory.

Let $1_{Y\ge y}$ the indicator function for the set $\{Y\ge y\}$. Then
$$
\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge y)\,dy = \int_0^\infty \int 1_{Y\ge y}\,dP\,dy=\int\int_0^\infty1_{Y\ge y}\,dy\,dP=\int Y\,dP=E[Y]
$$
The middle equality follows from the Fubini-Tonelli theorem. The third equality follows since $Y\ge0$, so the function $1_{Y\ge y}$ is $1$ on the interval $[0,Y]$, and $0$ elsewhere, so its integral over the real line is $Y$.