# What is the relationship between two formulas for expected value in terms of CDF?

Tags: probability, limits, expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

There are two formulas for expected value in terms of CDF:

$$
E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF_X(x)
$$

$$
E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_X(x)dx
$$

See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). Are they the same?

I tried to use Riemann–Stieltjes integral and prove they are the same. However, I cannot prove that:

$$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}x(1-F_X(x))=0
$$

There seems to be a proof in [this link](http://texasflood.github.io/2015/02/28/complementary-cdf-result/) but I don't get it. I think it assumes that the density function exists. Is this assumption necessary?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This might be an answer:

This is how I tried to prove this. Using integration by parts:
$$
\int_a^bf(x)dg(x)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)-\int_a^bg(x)df(x)
$$
we have:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F_X(x))-0-\int_{0}^{\infty}xd(1-F_X(x))\\
=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F_X(x))+\int_{0}^{\infty}xdF_X(x)
$$

Similarly,

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_X(x)dx=-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -\infty} xF_X(x)-\int_{-\infty}^{0}xdF_X(x)\\
=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} xF_X(-x)-\int_{-\infty}^{0}xdF_X(x)\\
=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F_X(x))-\int_{-\infty}^{0}xdF_X(x)
$$

Therefore,
$$
E(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F_X(x))-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} x(1-F_X(x))+\int_{0}^{\infty}xdF_X(x) +\int_{-\infty}^{0}xdF_X(x)
$$

Comment: Your [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) has a proof that does not presuppose existence of a density.

Comment: That one proves the 2nd equality. Does it prove that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F_X(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_X(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdF_X(x)$$.

Comment: Then what is your definition of $E[X]$?

Comment: Given $(S,F,P)$ as a probability space and the random variable $X\in \mathcal{L}^1$, $$E(X)=\int_{\mathcal{S}}X(w)dP(w)$$

Comment: Then it suffices to show this is equal to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2732385/321264

Comment: Thanks. The link did not help me much. However, I edited my question and provided more details (maybe a proof). Would you please check its validity