# Understanding $ \mathbb{E}((X-c) \mathbb{1}_{\{X > c\}}) = \int_c^{+\infty}\mathrm P(X\geqslant t)\,\mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

[For example, in this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85448/why-does-the-median-minimize-ex-c), it is claimed that the following holds:

$$
\mathrm E(|X-c|)=\int_{-\infty}^c\mathrm P(X\leqslant t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_c^{+\infty}\mathrm P(X\geqslant t)\,\mathrm dt
$$

The modulus part is clear, so it suffices to stick with the first part, namely:

$$ \mathbb{E}((X-c) \mathbb{1}_{\{X > c\}}) = \int_c^{+\infty}\mathrm P(X\geqslant t)\,\mathrm dt$$

Why does this hold? What I'm seeing is that: 
$$ \mathbb{E}((X-c) \mathbb{1}_{\{X > c\}}) = \int_{c}^{\infty}(u - c) \mathrm dF(u) = \int_{c}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{u-c} 1 \mathrm dw \mathrm dF(u) = \int_{c}^{\infty} \left(\int_{0}^{u-c} \mathrm dF(u) \right)  \mathrm dw $$

but can't make the last connection, especially since in my case integral limit depends on integrand value (using same $u$), hence I'm not even sure that such switching of integral order is possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use the fact that $E[Y] = \int_0^\infty P(Y \geq t)dt$ for any non-negative RV $Y$.

Comment: @TkiDeneb thanks for the hint! [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958472/expected-value-of-a-non-negative-random-variable) seems to prove that fact, I'll take a look at it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/explain-why-ex-int-0-infty-1-f-x-t-dt-for-every-nonnegative-rando?noredirect=1&lq=1