# Claim from an Actuarial Textbook: limits imply the existence of mean and variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, actuarial-science

This is from *Actuarial Mathematics for Life Contingent Risks*, 2nd ed., by Dickson et al. Some definitions (not directly from the book):

> **Definitions/Notation**. $T_x$ is defined to be the future lifetime of a life age $x \geq 0$. We also define the cumulative distribution function of $T_x$, denoted either $F_{T_x}$ or $F_x$, as $$F_{T_x}(t) = F_{x}(t) = \mathbb{P}\{T_x \leq t\}\text{.}$$
> The survival function of $T_x$, denoted $S_x$, is defined as $$S_{x}(t) = 1 - F_{x}(t)\text{.}$$
> It should also make sense that $T_x$ takes on only nonnegative values; i.e., $T_x \geq 0$. So, of course,$$\mathbb{E}\left[T_x\right] = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}tf_{x}(t)\text{ d}t$$
> where $f_{x}$ is the probability density function of $T_x$.

Throughout this textbook, it is assumed that $S_{x}$ is differentiable for all $t > 0$. The text also makes the following assumptions:

> **Assumption 2.2**: $\lim_{t \to \infty}tS_{x}(t) = 0$
>
> **Assumption 2.3**: $\lim_{t \to \infty}t^2S_{x}(t) = 0$
>
> "These last two assumptions ensure that the mean and variance of the distribution of $T_x$ exist."

Now here's the **main question**: *why is this true*? I can no longer find where I asked this before, but I recall that the *converse* is actually true (i.e., what the authors are stating here is indeed false), but never was able to find justification for *why*.

I also know for a fact that **IF** $\mathbb{E}[T_x]$ exists that
$$\mathbb{E}[T_x] = \int_{0}^{\infty}S_{x}(t) \text{ d}t\text{,}$$
but this is of course, not helpful, since it assumes that $\mathbb{E}[T_x]$ exists to begin with.

FYI: I am including [probability-theory](/questions/tagged/probability-theory) in this question in case we need tools from measure-theoretic probability to solve this question. Unfortunately, I don't know the topic very well.

Comment: Of course, simply positing that the existence of a 200 year old person is essentially impossible, or whatever other upper bound you like, establishes the existence of the mean and variance in an obvious way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conditions given by the OP are not sufficient (as suspected by the OP in the question).

A well-known formula in probability theory states that for nonnegative random variables $Y$:
$$ E[Y] = \int_0^\infty P(Y>y) dy , $$
see [Integral of CDF equals expected value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841/integral-of-cdf-equals-expected-value). This formula holds even if one of the sides above takes the value $+ \infty$.

Now we may use that formula to express the **mean** of the nonnegative random variable $T_x$:
$$ E[T_x] = \int_0^\infty S_x(t) dt.$$
So the mean is finite iff the integral on the right hand side is finite. Let $c= 2\log 2$. Then, the example $S_x(t) = c((t+2) \log (t+2))^{-1}$ for $t\in [0,\infty)$ shows:
\begin{align}
 \lim_{t\to \infty} tS_x(t) & = c\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t}{(t+2)\log (t+2)} = 0 \\
 \int_0^\infty S_x(t)dt & = c\int_0^\infty ((t+2) \log (t+2))^{-1} dt = c\int_2^\infty (s \log s)^{-1} ds =  c[\log (\log t)]^\infty_2 = \infty.
\end{align}
So, we see that Assumption 2.2 is not sufficient for the existence of the mean. We used $s=t+2$ in the integral.

Likewise the situation with the **variance** and the function 
\begin{equation} S_x(t) = c'\big((t+2)^2 \log (t+2) \big)^{-1}, t \in [0,\infty) .
\end{equation}
Here, $c' = 4 \log 2$. It is known that the variance exists iff the second moment exists. The derivation of the first steps for the second moment is then as follows.
$$ E[T_x^2] = \int_0^\infty P(T_x^2>t) dt = \int_0^\infty S_x(\sqrt{t})dt.$$
Almost the same calculation as above shows that Assumption 2.3 is not sufficient for the existence of the variance:
\begin{align}
 \lim_{t\to \infty} t^2S_x(t) & = c'\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{(t+2)^2\log (t+2)}  = 0 \\
 \int_0^\infty S_x(\sqrt{t})dt & = c'\int_0^\infty \big((\sqrt{t}+2)^2 \log (\sqrt{t}+2)\big)^{-1} dt = c'\int_2^\infty \big((s \log (\sqrt{s})\big)^{-1} dt \\
& = 2c'[\log (\log t)]^\infty_2 = \infty.
\end{align}
We used the substitution $\sqrt{s} = \sqrt{t} +2$ in the last line.

Comment: Your examples of $S_x(t)$ are not differentiable at $t=2$. But I think this can easily be fixed; all that is needed is a smaller value of $c$ (or $c'$) and a function that is $1$ at $t=0$ and that has the same value _and derivative_ as $c(t\log t)^{-1}$ (or $c'(t^2\log t)^{-1}$) at $t=2$. The end result is the same.

Comment: @thomas - Could you change the answer so that $c$ and $c^{\prime}$ are chosen such that $S_x$ is differentiable? If your proof is correct, I will grant you the bounty.

Comment: @thomas - Thank you for your changes!

Comment: @Clarinetist: you are welcome. The older version had $S_x(t) = c(t \log t)^{-1}$ for $t\geq 2$ and $S_x(t)=1$ for $t \in [0,2)$, which was not differentiable at $t=2$.

Answer (score 2):

I will give a general rule relating the tail behavior to the existence of certain moments of a random variable. This rule could then be used to *refine* assumptions 2.2 and 2.3.

Before, first note that your **IF** claim is fine, though if the mean does not exist the equality you mentioned still holds:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[T_x\right] &= \int_{0}^{\infty}t dF_x(t)\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{t>y}f_x(t)dydt\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}1_{t>y}dF_x(t)dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}Pr(T_x>y)dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}S_x(t)dt\\
\end{align}
I am allowed to change the order of integration by [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem).

In general, note that one could establish that if $\displaystyle t^aS_x(t)\rightarrow 0$ for some $\displaystyle a>0$ then $\displaystyle E|T_x|^b<\infty$ for $\displaystyle b<a$:
To see this note that (using integrations by part)
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{n}t^b dF_x(t)&=-n^bPr(T_x>n)+\int_{0}^{n}bt^{b-1}S_x(t)dt
\end{align}
now by $\displaystyle t^aS_x(t)\rightarrow 0$, for some $\displaystyle \epsilon >0$ we can choose $\displaystyle N=N(\epsilon)$ such that $\displaystyle Pr(T_x>t)<\frac{\epsilon}{t^a}$. Therefore $\displaystyle-t^bPr(T_x>t) \rightarrow 0$. Thus 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^b dF_x(t)&=\int_{0}^{N}bt^{b-1}S_x(t)dt+\int_{N}^{\infty}bt^{b-1}S_x(t)dt\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{N}bt^{b-1}dt + \int_{N}^{\infty}bt^{b-1}\frac{\epsilon}{t^a}dt\\
&<\infty
\end{align}

Comment: What does the notation $Pr(S_x > t)$ mean? Is $S_x$ a random variable introduced for this integration, and if so, what is its distribution?

Comment: In what way did you contradict the "if" claim? If I remember predicate logic correctly, for any propositions $P$ and $Q$ the implication $P\Rightarrow Q$ is _proved_, not contradicted, if $Q$ is shown to be true.

Comment: @DavidK Many thanks for the comments, I corrected the arguments.

Comment: @Clarinetist Many thanks for the comments. I do not agree with the author, in that I think we need $t^{1+\delta}S_x(t)\rightarrow 0$ with $\delta>0$ so that the mean exist which is stronger than $t^{1+0}S_x(t)\rightarrow 0$. About the second comment, I think this should not be a problem, since we are talking about $t$ being large (i.e. $t \rightarrow \infty$)

Comment: @Mehdi - Ah, I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @Mehdi - Sorry; my comments were completely off. Had a complete "duh" moment. I should have realized that limit was being done as $t \to \infty$, haha.