# Formula for $E(X^4)$ as integral of complementary CDF of random variable $X$

Tags: probability, expectation

So the question I have is

Let S be a non-negative random variable. By writing the probability as an expectation and using Fubini's theorm, show that

$ES^4=\int_0^\infty4t^3P(S>t)dt$

so I found on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition

[image]

but it does not show how to prove it.

My attempt is somehow using the chain rule but i don't know how do you change S into t.

Comment: $$S^4=\int_0^S4t^3\,dt=\int_0^\infty4t^3\mathbf 1_{S>t}\,dt$$

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Note that for $X$ non negative random variable, and $x>0$ and $\alpha > 1$

1. $$x^\alpha = \int_0^x\alpha u^{\alpha-1}du$$
2. $$E[X^\alpha] = \int_0^\infty x^\alpha dF(x)= \int_0^\infty \int_0^x\alpha u^{\alpha-1}du dF(x)$$
   $$ = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty\alpha u^{\alpha-1}1_{\{u \leq x\}}du dF(x)$$

Swap the integrals using Fubini Tonelli theorem, get rid of the indicator function and you will have your result. Try the steps for yourself and let me know if you have problems.

Comment: then $$\int_0^\infty1_{\{u \leq x\}}dF(x) = 1-F(u\leq x)=P(u>x)$$ ?

Comment: No. It evaluates to $\int_0^\infty 1_{\{u\leq x\}} dF(x) = \int_u^\infty  dF(x) = P[X  > u]$

Comment: Another way to understand this is to see that it is same as $E[1_{\{u \leq X\}}] = P[X > u]$

Comment: So my answer now would be using the symbols above would be $$E[S^4] \\ = \int_0^{\infty} S^4 dP \\ = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} 4t^3 1_{s>t} dtdP \\ =\mbox{Fubini} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} 4t^3 1_{s>t} dPdt \\ = \int_0^{\infty} 4t^3 \int_t^{\infty}  dPdt \\ = \int_0^{\infty} 4t^3 P(S>t) dt$$

Comment: Yes it is. Steps are all correct.

Comment: amazing thank you Gautam !

Comment: Actually there is serious mistake in the *very first step*, which should read $$E(S^4)=\int_\Omega S^4dP.$$ Note that this first step is unnecessary, one can do all that follows keeping the form $E(\cdots)$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing this on my phone so I hope there won't be that many typos.

If you assume that your random variable is nice enough, then it has a density function $f (t)$ and a distribution function $F(t) = P ( X \leq t)$ such that
$$\frac {d}{dt} (1 - F) = -f$$

In this case you can compute
\begin{align*}
E [X] &= \int X dP = \int t^{\alpha} dP_X = \int t^{\alpha} \cdot f (t) dt \\
& = - \int t^{\alpha} (1-F)'(t) dt = -[t^{\alpha}(1-F(t))]_{t=0}^{\infty} + \int \alpha  t^{\alpha - 1} (1-F(t)) dt \\
& = \alpha \int t^{\alpha-1} P (X > t ) dt
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks for your input but Fubini's Theorem needs to be applied