# Interchange Order of Integrals

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, expected-value

Can someone explain the last step in this process. Specifically, how do you get the new limits of integration?

Expected Value Definition: $E[Y] = \int_0^\infty{P\{Y \ge y\} \, dy}$

Expand: $E[Y] = \int_0^\infty{\int_y^\infty{f_Y(x) \, dx} \, dy}$

Clarify: $E[Y] = \int_{y=0}^{y=\infty}{\left(\int_{x=y}^{x=\infty}{f_Y(x) \, dx}\right) \, dy}$

Interchange order of integration: $E[Y] = \int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}{\left(\int_{y=0}^{y=x}{dy} \right) f_Y(x) \, dx}$

Comment: draw a picture of your domain of integration. it is really easy if you have visualized it.

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at this wiki article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29382/356647) to the current choice of [mother post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172841).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $f_Y$, the pdf of $Y\ge 0$, exists. In this case the expected value is

$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x\ f_Y(x)\ dx$$

Also, assume that the integral above is finite.

It is obvious that $x$ can be written as

$$x=\int_0^x\ 1\ dy, \ x\ge 0.$$

With this, the expected value is

$$E[Y]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_0^x\ 1\ dy\ f_Y(x)\ dx.$$

Since the expectation exists we can use Fubini' theorem so we can compute  this integral as a double integral.

$$E[Y]=\iint_A1\cdot d\mu(x,y)$$
where 
$$A=\{(x,y): 0\le y\le x\ \text{ and } 0 \le x < \infty \}.$$
and $\mu$ is the product measure of the probability measure generated by $f_Y$ and the Lebesgue measure. (For a rectangle $r=[a,b]\times [c,d]$, the measure  $\mu(r)=(b-a)\int_c^df_Y(x)\ dx$.)

The domain of the integration can be visualized:

[image]

Considering the definition of $\mu$ and the shape of the domain, and referring to Fubini's theorem, the double integral above can be written as

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{y}^{+\infty}\ 1\ f_Y(x)\ dx\ dy=$$
$$=\int_{0}^{+\infty}P(Y\ge y)\ dy.$$