# '$\wedge$' in the limit of a double integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, change-of-variable

I am confused with how to change the variables of the double integral below after invoking Fubini's Theorem; I am not very familiar with the wedge 'meet' notation which seems to arise. How is it that on changing the limits of the double integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^t\int_x^\infty f(y)g(x,y)\text{d}y\,\text{d}x$$

we obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\infty}^{t\wedge y} f(y)g(x,y)\text{d}x\,\text{d}y?$$

I have had a look at the question [Fubini's Theorem and Integral Bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2577146/fubinis-theorem-and-integral-bounds) and tried to follow the reasoning they used for changing the limits there. With that in mind, in our initial region is

$$\{(x,y):x\in(-\infty,t)\}\,\bigcap\,\{(x,y):y\in(x,\infty)\}.$$

I can see that the new $y$-region component will be $\{(x,y):y\in(-\infty,\infty)\}$, since we seen that $x$ originally varies from $-\infty$. The issue for changing the $x$-region component is that it doesn't involve $y$ explicitly; **how is it** that we then have as the new $x$-region $\{(x,y):x\in(-\infty,t\wedge y)\}$? And **what does the '$\wedge$' mean** exactly in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sketch the integration region and change the order of integration 'graphically'. Then you will notice that the upper bound for the $x$-variable is $\min (t,y)$. So $t \wedge y = \min(t,y)$.

Comment: As a side note: the notation $a \wedge b = \min \{ a, b \}$ isn't rare in measure theory, as well as $a \vee b = \max \{ a, b \}$.

Comment: I'll need to bear these in mind then; thanks! In the texts I have been going through so far I haven't encountered it until now.