# Probability Expectation proof

Tags: probability, expected-value

I dont know what to do, I have to proof this $$ E(X^n)=n\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F_{X}(x))x^{n-1}dx-n \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{0}F_{X}(x)x^{n-1}dx$$
 but i dont have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean $E(X^{n})$?

Comment: Show that $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(x))\ \mathsf dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(x)\ \mathsf dx$ using integration by parts, then use induction on $n$ to prove the general formula. Recall that $\mathbb E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\ \mathsf dF_X(x)$ - let $u=x$ and $\mathsf dv = \mathsf dF_X(x)$, and go from there.

Comment: The proof for $n=1$ is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136984/expectation-of-a-mixed-random-variable-given-only-the-cdf?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is easily generalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n\int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1} (1-F_X(x))dx=n\int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1} \int_{(x,\infty)} d\mu_X(y) dx$ where $\mu_X(E)=P(X^{-1}(E))$. By Fubini/Tonelli Theorem this becomes  $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{y} nx^{n-1} dx d\mu_X(y) =\int_0^{\infty} y^{n}d\mu_X(y) $. Similarly, the second term on RHS becomes $\int_{-\infty}^{0} y^{n}d\mu_X(y) $. Adding these we get $\int_{\mathbb R} y^{n}d\mu(y)$ which is $EX^{n}$.