# Converting piecewise CDF to PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For instance, I have the following CDF that I am trying to find the mean for, by firstly finding the PDF and then integrating over the interval.

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & x\leq -2 \\
          \frac{x+2}{4} & -2\leq x < 0 \\
          \frac{x^2 + 1}{2} & 0\leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
          \frac78 & \frac{1}{2} \leq x < 3 \\
           1  & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}$$

I understand that I need to differentiate $F(x)$ for each piece, however, for the 3rd piece, do I need to subtract the area of the first two functions first? Or do I differentiate normally yielding the pdf below?

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0, & x\leq -2 \\
          \frac{1}{4}, & -2\leq x < 0 \\
          x, & 0\leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
          0 & \text{otherwise}
       \end{cases}$$

Comment: It is just the derivative at each point.

Comment: You can find the mean from the CDF alone without looking for a PDF (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2136984/321264). Here of course PDF does not exist in the usual sense because $F$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually going to have a problem with this approach: the original CDF isn't continuous, which means that your random variable isn't continuous and won't have a genuine density function.  You can see what the issue will be by considering, for instance, the behavior at $x = 3$; note that the behavior of the CDF implies that $\mathbb P(X = 3) = 1/8$, which isn't something that continuous random variables do.

*If* your random variable was continuous, your approach would have been perfect for finding the density; but if you integrate the density you obtained, note that it doesn't give a total area of 1. You'll need to change your approach somewhat to proceed....

---

So, the original idea (which was good and will work in many important situations!) didn't work here. What to do?

This random variable is a hybrid of a discrete and a continuous random variable. It has discrete jumps at $x = 1/2$ and $x = 3$, but its CDF is continuous everywhere else.

The "density" you found will be helpful, because even though it doesn't have a total area of $1$, its area is $5/8$. Note also that the respective probabilities of the random variable being $1/2$ and $3$ are $1/4$ and $1/8$ -- meaning that in total, we've accounted for all the probability ($5/8 + 1/4 + 1/8 = 1$).

Remember what expected value is supposed to be: for a discrete variable, it's
$$\sum_{\text{all possible values}} \text{[value]} \cdot \mathbb P(X \text{ assumes that value})$$
and for a continuous variable it's
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) \, \textrm d x$$
where $f(x)$ is the density function. You might guess (correctly) that a mixed approach will work here:

$$\mathbb E[X] = \frac 1 2 \cdot \mathbb P(X = 1/ 2) + 3 \cdot \mathbb P(X = 3) + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f(x) \, \textrm d x$$
where $f(x)$ is the not-quite-a-density-function you correctly found in your original post.

I think this approach is challenging to prove / justify at a non-measure-theoretic level, but hopefully it at least makes some intuitive sense; you're capturing the full range of what $X$ can do, and appropriately weighting each possible value of $X$ against its density function.

Comment: Ok so finding the derivative at each point is not the way to go, how would I go about proceeding?

Comment: Before I answer, what level of probability is this? Have you seen things like measure theory / Fubini's Theorem? (It's easier to answer if you have, but it's still possible to argue if you haven't seen measure-theoretic probability yet.)

Comment: I'm afraid not, this assumes undergrad stats background