# Comparing the mean of two continuous random variable when one's CDF is always greater than the other

Tags: probability

Suppose that for two continuous random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, the below condition holds.

$$
F_{X_2}(x) \geq F_{X_1}(x)
$$

for all $x \in R$ and $F$ stands for CDF.

Then can I say that the mean of $X_1$ is always greater than the mean of $X_2$? (assume that mean of both of them are finite)

If so, what would be the proof of that?

Comment: [Stochastic dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Thank you so much Aaron Hendrickson!

Comment: Also relevant: [Monotone Likelihood Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_likelihood_ratio?wprov=sfla1). See bit about stochastic dominance later in the article.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is nonnegative, you can use the following relation to compute the expectation from the distribution.
$$
E(X) = \int_0^\infty 1-F_X(x) \, dx.
$$
The result you are looking for follows from that equality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what if the X can be negative??

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ can be negative, use the identity
$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty[1-F_X(t)]dt-\int_{-\infty}^0 F_X(t)dt,$$
to show that $E(X_2)\le E(X_1)$.

(The identity is valid whenever $E(X)$ exists, and is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137144/215011).)